# Can I make a plot with gradient filling?

Tags: plotting, filling

Bloomberg has a standard plot style for its line plots in which it uses a gradient filling. Actually the way this seems to be constructed is that a gradient from the ymax to ymin is used as the background in the plot area and then the area above the line is set to transparent

[image].

What is the best way to make a plot like that in Mathematica for plotting {x,y} data?

Comment: An observation: the color scheme of all the parts of that plot, together, is hideously unattractive to my eyes. And having the background, above the line plot, such a dark color seems a particularly bad choice.

Comment: Does anyone else find it odd that a gradient oriented at right angles to this (blending left to right) is as easy as specifying `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue}, #1] &)`, but a top-to-bottom blend is so complex?

Comment: I wonder what Edward Tufte would have to say about that chart...

Comment: I guess Bloomberg never consulted Tufte.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this?

```
bankerPlot[data_] := ListLinePlot[
  data,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Prolog -> Polygon[Join[data, Reverse[data.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0}]]],
    VertexColors -> Join[
      Blend[{Black, Blue}, #] & /@ Normalize[data[[All, 2]], Max],
      ConstantArray[Black, Length[data]]
      ]
    ],
  PlotStyle -> White,
  Background -> Black,
  AxesStyle -> White
  ]

bankerData = Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];
bankerPlot[bankerData]
```

[image: bankerPlot output]

Comment: nice one! I'll leave the question open for a little while but this looks like a winner :)

Comment: BTW in my testing I changed from `Epilog` to `Prolog` because you lose the solid line otherwise (on my system anyway)

Comment: Aha I think we caught that at about the same time. See my latest edit, 7 minutes after my first answer.

Comment: +1 for the function name (banker + plot = very sinister).

Comment: I like both these methods but I find this one more intuitive than using `ParametricPlot`. For others it may be different. This one also seems to render faster -- not that the timings are significant enough to be a deciding factor but thought I would mention it anyway.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens great answer. Your model can be migrated to DateListPlot. bankerPlot[data_] := 
 DateListPlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {data[[1, 1]], 0}, 
  Prolog -> 
   Polygon[Join[
     data, {DateList[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ \
(Reverse[({AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ data).DiagonalMatrix[{1,
            0}]])], 
    VertexColors -> 
     Join[Blend[{Black, Blue}, #] & /@ Normalize[data[[All, 2]], Max],
       ConstantArray[Black, Length[data]]]], PlotStyle -> White, 
  Background -> Black, AxesStyle -> White, FrameStyle -> White, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}];

Comment: koStock = FinancialData["KO", {2013, 1, 1}] ;bankerPlot[koStock]

Answer (score 23):

For plotting a continuous function, you could do something like this:

```
f[x_] := (1 + Cos[5 x]/2) Sin[x] 

ParametricPlot[{x, f[x] y}, {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 30,
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue, White}, #2] &), Mesh -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

This method can be used for plotting a list of points as well by interpolating the points first, e.g.

```
pts1 = RandomReal[10, 100];

interpol = Interpolation[pts1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

ParametricPlot[{x, interpol[x] y}, {x, 1, Length[pts1]}, {y, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Blue, White}, #2] &), Mesh -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi Heike, what I had in mind was for plotting {x,y} data only.

Comment: I like the edit. I can almost replicate @ArgentoSapiens except that PlotStyle->White doesn't seem to be controlling the line colour.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Try `BoundaryStyle -> White`.

Comment: @BrettChampion thanks for that.

Answer (score 19):

Here's a modification of Heike's `ParametricPlot` approach, using textures instead of `ColorFunction`.

```
pts1 = RandomReal[10, 100];

interpol = Interpolation[pts1, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

ParametricPlot[{u, interpol[u] v}, {u, 1, Length[pts1]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], 
   Texture[Table[{{##}} & @@ Blend[{Black, Blue, White}, 1-i], 
      {i, 0, 1, 0.01}]]}]
```

> [image]

I'm using a 1-pixel wide `Image` containing the black-blue-white gradient Heike used.  (Actually, it doesn't have an `Image` head; it's just the `ImageData`.)

I'm also specifying that I want the texture to correspond to the $x$ and $y$ coordinates instead of the default of $u$ and $v$.

This approach allows us to generalize the gradient to something more complicated, or even an arbitrary image:

```
ParametricPlot[{u, interpol[u] v}, {u, 1, Length[pts1]}, {v, 0, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &), 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks Brett. I can see where I might want to use this with country's flag as a texture.

Answer (score 17):

This is a variant of Argento's answer with the blend on a rectangle in the background rather than creating a polygon that matches the data.

```
bankerData = 
  Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];


ListLinePlot[bankerData, Frame -> True, Background -> Black, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{1, 100}, {0, 20}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 BaseStyle -> {Thick, White, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 13}, 
 Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, White], 
 Prolog -> 
  Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
    Scaled[{0, 1}]}, VertexColors -> {Black, Black, Blue, Blue}]]
```

[image]

The disadvantage of my approach is that you need to set `PlotRangePadding->0`.

Comment: hmmm, I like this one the best now :). I usually set `PlotRangePadding->0` by default anyway so that would not be an issue for me.

Comment: @Verbeia, blue artifacts appear when trying to migrate the model to DateListPlot (to take advantage of FinancialData. koStock = FinancialData["KO", {2013, 1, 1}]; DateListPlot[koStock, 
 AxesOrigin -> {First@koStock[[All, 1]], 0}, Frame -> True, 
 Background -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> {Thick, White, FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 13}, 
 Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, White], 
 Prolog -> 
  Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
    Scaled[{0, 1}]}, VertexColors -> {Black, Black, Blue, Blue}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]

Answer (score 14):

Here is another method that uses the more general gradient background construction I posted as an answer to ["How can I set different opacity values for the background of a ListPlot"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16133/245).

This answer is rather late, but I thought it's a good example of how else to use the simple option `Prolog -> gradientBackground` to create a gradient background:

```
gradientBackground = 
  With[{bottomColor = Black, topColor = Lighter[Blue]}, 
   Inset[Show[
     Rasterize[
      Graphics[
       Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
        VertexColors -> {bottomColor, bottomColor, topColor, 
          topColor}], PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], 
      "Image"], AspectRatio -> Full], {Left, Bottom}, {0, 0}, 
    ImageScaled[{1, 1}]]];


bankerData = 
  Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];

ListLinePlot[
 bankerData,
 Prolog -> gradientBackground,
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotStyle -> White,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True},
 PlotRegion -> {{.04, .96}, {.04, .96}},
 Background -> Black,
 Filling -> Top,
 FillingStyle -> Black,
 PlotRange -> All,
 BaseStyle -> {White, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image: banker plot]

Answer (score 10):

While trying to force `ColorFunction` to work I came up with this:

```
bankerData = Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];

bands = 20;

ListLinePlot[Table[{1, i} # & /@ bankerData, {i, 0`, 1`, 1/bands}], 
 Background -> Black, AxesStyle -> White, 
 ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors", 
 Filling -> True
]
```

[image]

Adding `Mesh -> True` gives an idea of how it works:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

If you can accept the limitation of a two-color gradient here is another option:

```
bankerData = 
  Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];

p1 = ListLinePlot[
       bankerData, 
       ColorFunction -> ({Black, Red} ~Blend~ #2 &),
       Filling -> Axis
     ];

n = Length @ bankerData;

MapAt[Join[# ~Take~ n, Black & /@ # ~Drop~ n] &, p1, {1, -1, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The index `{1, -1, 2}` is for the `VertexColors` list.  It works on version 7.  If it does not work on your version either find the right index, or use patterns, e.g.:

```
pos = {#, #2, 2} & @@ Position[p1, VertexColors][[-1]];

MapAt[Join[#~Take~n, Black & /@ #~Drop~n] &, p1, pos]
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to consider a bar chart instead, this can be done with sufficient segments in a `"SegmentScaleRectangle"` setting for `ChartElementFunction`. Rendering is a little slow but the result is quite attractive.

```
testdata = 
  FoldList[0.99 #1 + #2 &, 0., 
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]];

BarChart[testdata, ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None], BarSpacing -> 0, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
 ChartElementFunction -> 
  ChartElementDataFunction["SegmentScaleRectangle", "Segments" -> 200,
    "ColorScheme" -> "SunsetColors"]]
```

[image]

This works fine with dark backgrounds: all one needs to do is add
`BaseStyle -> White, Background->Black` to the options in the `BarChart` or `RectangleChart`.

Answer (score 3):

New-in-version-12.2.0 styling directive [`LinearGradientFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearGradientFilling.html) makes the task more straightforward:

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "OHLCV", {{2009, 5, 1}, {2010, 4, 30}}]; 

DateListPlot[data["PathComponent", 4], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[.7]], PlotMarkers -> None, 
 Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle ->
    LinearGradientFilling[{Black, Darker@Darker@Blue, Blue, LightBlue},  Top], 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing", 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.4], Dashed], 
 Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]