# Torn edge paper effect for images

Tags: image-processing

In my answers to [Plotting Error Bars on a Log Scale](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/plotting-error-bars-on-a-log-scale/3899#3899) I used a so called "torn edge" effect from on one of the images. @SjoerdC.deVries commented: "BTW I liked the ripped-out look of your InputForm picture; Mathematica? It's ideal for pictures that have to convey the message "There's more of this, but that's not important". Though it was a software called Snagit, I think *Mathematica* can easily do it. For example, this train of thought:

Imagine you have an image which you'd like to limit with torn edge:

```
a = Image[Rasterize[RandomReal[1, 50], RasterSize -> 700]]
```

[image]

Generate random walk:

```
b = ListLinePlot[SeedRandom[4]; Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2000]],
   Axes -> False, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> White, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/13,  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.0015], GrayLevel[.0], 
  Opacity[.5]}, PlotRangePadding -> {0, 5, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Make shadow:

```
c = ListLinePlot[SeedRandom[4]; Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2000]],
   Axes -> False, Filling -> Bottom, FillingStyle -> White, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/13, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005], Opacity[.3], 
  GrayLevel[.2]}, PlotRangePadding -> {0, 5, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

And compose everything:

```
d = ImageCompose[b, c, {Left, Bottom}, {Left, 5}];
e = ImageCompose[a, d, {Left, Bottom}, {Left, Bottom}];
ImageCompose[e, ImageRotate[d, Pi/2], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]
```

[image]

This kind of works - but is obviously very raw. Right bottom corner is problematic for example. So can we make it work? Some perhaps good things to think of:

- Single function where we feed image and pointers which edges to torn.
- All image sizes would work
- All methods are good, no need to use random walks

This question maybe helpful: [How can I make a 2D line plot with a drop shadow under the line?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/how-can-i-make-a-2d-line-plot-with-a-drop-shadow-under-the-line)

Comment: Vitaliy: see here http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/for-sale-three-potentially-useful-palettes

Answer (score 70, accepted):

A bit lengthy, but here's my attempt. The parameters in `torn` are the base image `img` and an array describing which edges should be torn. This array is of the form `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`, where a `0` corresponds to a straight edge and any non-zero value to a torn edge, so `{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}` would correspond to an image where only the bottom edge is torn.

```
Options[torn] = {"amplitude" -> .04, "frequency" -> 50, "offset" -> {10, 10}, 
   "opacity" -> .7, "gaussianBlur" -> 4};

torn[img_, {{l_, r_}, {b_, t_}}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{ratio, left, right, bottom, top, poly, img1, shadow, amp, dx, offset},
  ratio = #2/#1 & @@ ImageDimensions[img];
  amp = OptionValue["amplitude"] {Min[1/ratio, 1], Min[ratio, 1]};
  dx = 1/(OptionValue["frequency"] {Min[1/ratio, 1], Min[ratio, 1]});
  offset = Abs[{##}] UnitStep[{#1 {-1, 1}, #2 {1, -1}}] & @@ OptionValue["offset"];

  left = If[l == 0, {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 
   Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1} amp[[2]]], i}, {i, 1 - amp[[2]], dx[[2]], -dx[[2]]}]];
  right = If[r == 0, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}, 
   Table[{1 + RandomReal[{-1, 0} amp[[2]]], i}, {i, dx[[2]], 1 - amp[[2]], dx[[2]]}]];
  bottom = If[b == 0, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, 
   Table[{i, RandomReal[{0, 1} amp[[1]]]}, {i, dx[[1]], 1 - amp[[1]], dx[[1]]}]];
  top = If[t == 0, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   Table[{i, 1 + RandomReal[{-1, 0} amp[[1]]]}, {i, 1 - amp[[1]], dx[[1]], -dx[[1]]}]];
  poly = Join[left, bottom, right, top];

  {img1, shadow} = 
    Image@Graphics[#, ImagePadding -> OptionValue["gaussianBlur"], 
        PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> ratio, Background -> None, 
        ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img] + 2 OptionValue["gaussianBlur"]] & /@
     {{Texture[img], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[poly, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly]}, 
      {Polygon[poly]}};
  img1 = ImagePad[img1, offset, {1, 1, 1, 0}];
  shadow = ImagePad[GaussianFilter[shadow, OptionValue["gaussianBlur"]],
      Reverse /@ offset, {1, 1, 1, 0}];
  ImageCompose[img1, {shadow, OptionValue["opacity"]}, Center, Center, {1, 1, -1}]]
```

There are a number of options which control various image parameters. These are the amplitude of the tears `"amplitude"`, the frequency of the jags, `"frequency"`, the opacity of the shadow, `"opacity"`, and the blurriness of the shadow `"gaussianBlur"`. The offset of the shadow towards the lower right corner is controlled by the option `"offset"` which is off the form `{right, bottom}` where `right` and `bottom` are in points. Negative values for `right` and `bottom` indicate a shadow pointing towards the left and/or top of the image.

**Example**

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
torn[img, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, "offset" -> {20, 20}, "gaussianBlur" -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Apparently, under certain circumstances Mathematica doesn't render a transparent background for `img1` which results in a white region between the image and the shadow. I managed to reproduce this behaviour in version 8.0.1 for OS X with `img = Image@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`, but not in 8.0.4. It seems that setting the `ImageSize` in `Graphics` is the culprit. To resolve this issue I replaced `{img1, shadow} = Image@Graphics...` in `torn` with

```
{img1, shadow} = 
  Rasterize[
     Graphics[#, ImagePadding -> OptionValue["gaussianBlur"], 
      PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> ratio, 
      Background -> None], 
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img] + 2 OptionValue["gaussianBlur"], 
     Background -> None] & /@ 
   {{Texture[img], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[poly, VertexTextureCoordinates -> poly]}, 
    {Polygon[poly]}};
```

Comment: Wow, very neat implementation - love the look of it :)

Comment: I found I had to add in an extra `Image[...]` to make it work in general: `img1 = ImagePad[Image[Graphics[..., Background->None], ...`

Comment: Wow o_o this is amazing :)

Comment: @wxffles It's a lovely effect, as you mentioned it didn't quite work for me out of the box and I couldn't quite figure out where to make your adaption in the code?

Comment: @image_doctor What goes wrong with the code above? I've edited the code since wxffles's remark so adding `Image[...]` shouldn't have to be necessary any more.

Comment: @Heike, thanks for responding. I've taken a fresh copy of the code. It seems as though the background for the mandrill image isn't transparent, so there is a solid white region in between the torn image and the shadow.

Comment: @image_doctor Which version are you using? I couldn't reproduce this behaviour in 8.0.4 for OS X, only in version 8.0.1. I've posted a solution which solves the issue in my version at least.

Comment: @Heike Thank you for looking into that,  I'm using Linux 64 bit 8.0.0.0.

Comment: @Heike Thank you so much, the fixed worked fine for me.

Comment: I posted a palette [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/for-sale-three-potentially-useful-palettes)

Answer (score 11):

With the [release of M11.2](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/09/14/its-another-impressive-release-launching-version-11-2-today/) I finally can add an answer via a built-in function. Let's get the test image:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];
```

Now it becomes as easy as this:

```
torn = ImageEffect[i, {"TornFrame", Scaled[1/15], {Right, Bottom}, .05}]
```

[image]

Note there is no shadow to dramatize the effect. It can be achieved by various methods, for instance (we are making this mask slightly larger than original image):

```
shadow = ImageResize[
            Blur[ColorNegate[Binarize[ColorQuantize[torn, 1]]], 20], 
         Scaled[1.02]]
```

[image]

```
ImageCompose[shadow, torn, {Left, Top}, {Left, Top}]
```

[image]

I still like @Heike answer very much ;-)

Comment: Heike's result is much more irregular. Does `Scale` play on the irregularity of the cut? (I don't have v11.2 to try) Thanks for the update anyway.

Comment: @anderstood Please look at my answer where I show how to reproduce Heike's result with v.11.2 `ImageEffect`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov this is wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

### Update

Here is a non-hackish way to reproduce the [Heike's style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/280) of torn edges using `ImageEffect` of version 10.2 with even higher irregularity (irregular steps):

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];

t = Module[{step = 10, if, n = 2 Total[ImageDimensions[i]], k = 0}, 
 if = Interpolation[
   Transpose[{Accumulate[Prepend[RandomInteger[{step, 2 step}, n], 0]], 
     RandomReal[1, n + 1]}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]; 
 ImageEffect[i, {"Frame", if[++k] &, 15, {Right, Bottom}}]]
```

> [image]

---

### Original answer

An extension of the [answer by Vitaliy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155774/280). We can reproduce the [Heike's style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/280) of torn edges with `ImageEffect` of version 10.2 by `Block`ing the `Accumulate` function:

```
i = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];

t = Block[{Accumulate = RandomReal[1, Length[#]] &}, 
  ImageEffect[i, {"TornFrame", Scaled[1/15], {Right, Bottom}, .08}]]
```

> [image]

(the hack is found by tracing the evaluation of `ImageEffect`).

Here is how to add a semi-transparent shadow:

```
offset = 10;
blur = 5;
shadowTone = .5;
ImageCompose[SetAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@#, #] &@Blur[
   ImageMultiply[ImagePad[AlphaChannel[t], {{offset, blur/2}, {blur/2, offset}}],
    shadowTone], blur],
 ImagePad[t, {{0, offset + blur/2}, {offset + blur/2, 0}}]]
```

> [image]

Sometimes it is desirable to highlight the boundary:

```
boundaryLigntness = .4;
ImageCompose[
 SetAlphaChannel[ColorNegate@#, #] &@Blur[
   ImageMultiply[ImagePad[AlphaChannel[t], {{offset, blur/2}, {blur/2, offset}}], 
    shadowTone], blur],
 ImagePad[ImageMultiply[t, 
   ColorNegate@ImageMultiply[MorphologicalPerimeter@AlphaChannel[t], boundaryLigntness]],
  {{0, offset + blur/2}, {offset + blur/2, 0}}]]
```

> [image]

Comment: I really like your ideas. Could you make a post on Wolfram Community about how to make this nice edge and also add shadow?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Posted on WC: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1188397