# How can I visualize features found in an image?

Tags: image-processing, visualization

I am using Mathematica to explore the face detection feature of Core Image on Mac OS X Lion. To do this I have an Objective-C program which captures images from the iSight camera, runs face detection and logs the coordinates of any detected features, and then saves the image to the clipboard. I then switch to Mathematica and paste the captured image into one variable, and copy-and-paste the logged feature coordinates into another.

I've written a simple Mathematica function that can subsequently produce a "normalized" face image, but it would be helpful to be able to draw graphics on top of an image in order to visualize where features are and how they're oriented. When I naively try this I get the error: "Image is not a graphics primitive or directive."

Is there a simple way to draw (or composite) graphics on top of an image?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Show` can combine `Image` and `Graphics`:

```
a = ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Oakland2"}];
b = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[{400, 400}, 300]}];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

In this way you can do it in a programmatic way. But you can also do this manually and interactively via right-click menu access to **Drawing Tools**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That torn edge looks suspiciously like [Heike's method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/52). :)

Comment: Just what the doctor ordered, thanks!

Comment: @rcollyer nice name haha :)

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf whatever works. :)

Comment: @rcollyer indeed ;-)

Comment: `Show` works with `Image` only starting from *Mathematica* 8 and it is not reflected in the Documentation for `Show`. Did not know this, +1.

Answer (score 4):

You can also achieve the same effects with `ImageCompose`

```
a = ExampleData[{"AerialImage", "Oakland2"}];
b = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Thick, Circle[{200, 200}, 300], 
    Circle[{1500, 200}, 200], Circle[{0, 0}, 200]}];

ImageCompose[a, b]
```

And also with `Overlay`:

```
Overlay[{a, b}, Alignment -> {Center}]
```

Though the co-ordinate system is not consistent between the two.

Comment: Just to note that result produced by `Overlay` will be neither `Graphics` or `Image`. Sometimes people are surprised by that :)

Comment: I'm suitably surprised :) It appears to be ... an Overlay !