# How to place an image inside a notebook, with the minimum memory footprint?

Tags: import, notebooks, image, memory

When creating a notebook with images, like photos, the file tends to quickly get big, which makes it difficult to use the notebook format for training material containing a lot of images.

*Are there different ways of passing an image into a notebook, in relation to memory used?*

(Please note that the purpose is to show the images in the “middle” of other content, like text, etc, and not simply have the image information in some kind of abstract code)

I've noticed that every time I copy an image to a notebook, its `FullForm` reveals that it is "stored" with an "exhaustive" description of each pixel color value(s).

- Is there a way of storing it with indexed color definition (like the GIF format)?
- Is there a way of storing it with some kind of compression (like JPEG or similar)?

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I discovered the following curiosity: if I `Import` a GIF file (of my printscreen), and then save it, my file gets to 150 kb. If I save it again (without changing anything), it gets reduced to 32 kb.

If instead of `Import`ing it, I just copy it from the clipboard to the notebook, it always keeps the 150 kb.

Comment: Is the issue big memory footprint when opening the notebook, or large file size?  I might have something for large file size, but not for large memory usage...

Comment: @Szabolcs large file size (which also ends up in a long time to open)

Comment: My answer should help the large file size, but not the time to open ...

Comment: Thanks for the question, P.Fonseca - I think we're learning some new things here.

Comment: @Jen Thank you all for the contribution :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The technique is mentioned in one of Wolfram CDF virtual conference talks ([See the course:
Developing Real-World CDF Applications](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-cdf-virtual-workshop-2012/)), as well as being used in a lot of CDF examples ([for instance, the slideshow at the beginning of this example](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/infographics-full-example.html)) but I will repeat it here, with some improvement.

### Recompressing images with better compression

(Note: While writing an answer, **Rojo** already provided the same method.)

As it is mentioned by other users here, you don't have to manually use `Compress` since images are already being compressed using it when being stored inside a notebook cell. `Compress` is based on gzip and it is overall OK, except that it can be pretty horrible with images.

Let's try to use other compression, for instance PNG (lossless) or JPEG (lossy) (or anything for that matter). Let's say our image is `img`. I am grabbing an image from the Hubble Gallery as an example.

```
url = "http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2006-01-a-1920x1200_wallpaper.jpg";

img = Import[url];
```

This is a pretty big image.

```
In[3]:= ByteCount[img]
Out[3]= 6912464
```

Now, compress it using the compression of your choice and store it as string using `ExportString`.

```
jpeg = ExportString[img, "JPEG"];
```

Of course, you can use any other compression (for instance, "PNG" or "GIF") or control compression rate for JPEG by using `"CompressionLevel"` option (default is 0.25).

To embedded this data in a cell, it has to be converted to `Base64` (essentially using non-special characters).

```
base64 = ExportString[jpeg, "Base64"]
```

This is a slightly larger than actual binary JPEG, but still far smaller than uncompressed size, or compressed size.

```
In[6]:= ByteCount[base64]
Out[6]= 219224
```

(To be fair, Mathematica will save it using aforementioned `Compress` and the size will be smaller than what `ByteCount[img]` is reporting, but not this small).

By using `ImportString`, you can convert it back to the image:

```
ImportString[base64, "Base64"]
```

(You don't have to call `ImportString` again for the compression, since it will be automatically taken care of)

To embedded the raw data (`jpeg`) and let FrontEnd uncompress it during the time of reading a notebook, try the following code.

```
With[{a = base64}, Dynamic[ImportString[a, "Base64"], SingleEvaluation->True]]
```

*or*

```
With[{a = base64}, Dynamic[Refresh[ImportString[a, "Base64"], None]]]
```

The extra option (`SingleEvaluation`) and [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refresh.html) are used to make sure that it is evaluated just once. Also, `With` is needed to ensure that the embedded cell contains the content of `base64`, instead of a symbol `base64`. This can play nicely with other cells, such as texts and other graphics, using `Row` or other constructions.

Now, let's try to save it. First try:

```
nb = CreateDocument[With[{a = base64},
  Dynamic[ImportString[a, "Base64"], SingleEvaluation -> True]]];

NotebookSave[nb, "jpeg.nb"]
```

Try to check the size of the file, and you will be surprised...

[image: size]

It is smaller than a notebook with just the image (which will be around 5MB), but still not quite as smaller as we expected it to be. What's wrong? It is because Mathematica caches images by default. Let's disable it (`CacheGraphics->False` will do it. You can set it using the Option Inspector too).

```
nb2 = CreateDocument[With[{a = base64},
  Dynamic[ImportString[a, "Base64"], SingleEvaluation -> True]], CacheGraphics->False];

NotebookSave[nb2, "jpeg2.nb"]
```

Now, much reasonable:

[image: size2]

### Using native compression of imported image

Sometimes, your image is coming from external source with its own native compression. The problem with the first approach is that it essentially uncompress it then recompress using different compression / rate (sort of transcoding...). In particularly with lossy compression like JPEG, it may leads to image distortion. To minimize this, you can do the following.

(Note: **Szabolcs** provided a nice solution using `Import`. Thank you)

We can read the file's native binary data by caling `Import[..., "String"]`.

```
jpeg = Import[url, "String"];
```

<strike>First, the image has to be in local storage. Bring its native binary data using `BinaryReadList`. Also, use `"Character8"` and `StringJoin` so that it will turn into the string of binary data.</strike>

```
jpeg = StringJoin@@BinaryReadList["hs-2006-01-a-1920x1200_wallpaper.jpg", "Character8"];
```

It should be about the same size as the original file (+/- some due to the string representation in Mathematica). From here, you can follow the above steps to turn it into "Base64" and then embed.

### Reading image from online

If you have a lot of images, then this can be applicable.

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Import[url], None]]
```

If it times out, you can increase the timeout using [`DynamicEvaluationTimeout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html) or try the following to show a nice indicator while loading.

```
DynamicModule[{img = None}, 
 Dynamic[If[img === None, 
   ProgressIndicator[Clock[Infinity], Indeterminate], img], 
  TrackedSymbols :> {}],
 Initialization :> (img = 
    Import["http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2006-01-a-1920x1200_wallpaper.jpg"]),
 SynchronousInitialization -> False]
```

This course [notebook](http://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/wolfram-cdf-virtual-workshop-2012/files/DevelopingRealWorldCDFApplications.zip) contains some useful examples including a spinner for progress and such.

Also, these techniques can be used to embed any large data, such as MOV file!

Comment: Thanks for the additional links (+1) - looks like we figured out many of these things independently, but your  explanations make me more confident that we're not abusing `Dynamic` too badly, if Wolfram suggests it for the same purpose.

Comment: Instead of `BinaryReadList` and `StringJoin`, could we use `Import[..., "String"]` instead, or are there any differences?  `Import[..., "String"]` is very fast in my experience, so performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: If you're interested, this topic would make a nice [blog post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/419/12).

Comment: One problem with this technique is that one must take care when copying the images around.  If I click the image to select it (with the orange frame and resize grips around it), and copy to another notebook, the actual large size image will be copied.  If I select the image by clicking and dragging (the same way we usually select text), then the whole `DynamicBox` will be copied.  Is there any trick to prevent the user from accidentally copying the image data only, and losing the `DynamicBox`?  We could use `Deploy` around `Dynamic`, but then we lose resizing.

Comment: @Szabolcs, you are right about `Import[..., "String"]`. It was an old habit. I modified the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Szabolcs, the copying behavior is interesting question. I think that it is doable, but not through the standard ctrl(cmd)+c combo (that may be tricky... I have never tried to intercept standard shortcuts), but rather through the context (right-click) menu. Let me try.

Comment: @Yu-SungChang It *is* possible to copy it, but the trick is that I need to select by a mouse drag (not a simple click), the same way I select text.  This seems to be possible only if I wrap the image in Dynamic, or if there's some additional content in the cell next to the image.

Comment: @Yu-Sung Chang You nicely explained how to programmatically create the notebook with a memory-reduced image. Is there a simple way to make it directly. I mean that the image or heavy graphics may be created within a target notebook. The target I use to denote the notebook, where the final images should stay, and the aim is to make it to occupy less memory. The problem is then, how to compress it in place? Alternatively, one may create the graphics in a separate notebook and then copy it into the target notebook. How to copy it with the condition CacheGraphics->False?

Comment: Is there a simple way to apply this to all the images in every cell in a notebook?

Answer (score 19):

There is something you can do. I just tried it with a `JPEG` image that I pasted into a notebook. The original image had `900kB` and the notebook with only that image had `11.2 MB`!

Let's say you have an image in an output cell of your notebook, then select the cell bracket, go to `Cell > Convert To... > Bitmap` and the resulting notebook will be much smaller.

In my test case, the result was `766kB`, i.e., less than the original image. The size reduction is not due to a different compression, but it reduces the size of the pasted graphic to a size appropriate for the notebook display.

**Edit**

Mathematica's compression format doesn't seem to be very efficient, even compared to the ubiquitous `Base64` format. Just for fun, I compared the sizes of some compressed images - here is an example:

```
a = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];
pic = ExportString[a, "GIF"];
string1 = Compress[pic];
string2 = ExportString[pic, "Base64"];

StringLength[string1]
(* ==> 28114 *)

StringLength[string2]
(* ==> 21406 *)
```

The last result shows that `Base64` encoding is more efficient for this `GIF` image. To reconstruct the base64-encoded image, one would say `ImportString[string2, "Base64"]`.

Unfortunately, I currently don't know of a way to make use of this observation for the purposes of actually displaying images...

**Edit 2**

Rojo made an interesting suggestion that relies on `Dynamic` (and which could therefore be slow if many images need to appear in the visible part of the notebook at the same time). It would work basically as if the notebook is a web page that loads its images from the disk:

Assume you have an image `image.jpg` in the working directory of your notebook, then the single line

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Import["~/Pictures/image.jpg"], None]]
```

will display the image in its original form when it's executed. You could make this cell an initialization cell to make sure it does its job of loading the image. **Addendum:** However, if (as above) I include the *absolute path* to the image in the `Import` statement, the notebook displays the image automatically as soon as you've permitted `Dynamic` to be enabled.

The downside is that the image is *not* stored inside the notebook as the original question demands.

However, the upside is that the notebook is extremely light-weight.

**Edit 3**

Since Yu-Sung Chang mentions in his answer that this method can also be used to embed external Quicktime movies, I tried it and was indeed successful with the following command:

```
Style[Dynamic[
  Refresh[Import[
    "http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/StopMotion.mov", 
    "Animation"], None]], DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60]
```

This example uses a remote URL, but the same also works with local URLs. The setting `DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60` is added as a `Style` directive; without it, the command aborts.

You can copy the resulting output cell (or similarly the one from the previous image example) by selecting the **cell bracket** first. What you're really copying and saving can be illustrated by selecting the output cell and doing `Cell > Show Expression...`:

```
Cell[BoxData[
 StyleBox[
  DynamicBox[ToBoxes[
    Refresh[
     Import[
     "http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/computernotes/StopMotion.mov",
     "Animation"], None], StandardForm],
   ImageSizeCache->{589., {265., 273.}}],
  StripOnInput->False,
  DynamicEvaluationTimeout->60]], "Output",
 CellChangeTimes->{
  3.547335674114159*^9, {3.5473357563388443`*^9, 
   3.547335785166815*^9}, {3.54733584467654*^9, 
   3.5473358540852947`*^9}, 3.547335895905892*^9, 
   3.5473365158725147`*^9, 3.547336769935759*^9}]
```

There is no actual movie data in this cell, and that's why the notebook is extremely small when saved to a file.

Comment: An idea I haven't tried... What about something like `Dynamic[Refresh[ImportString[string2, "Base64"], None]]`?

Comment: @Rojo That idea points to a completely different approach: first, I thought this won't help because the `string2` that you want to display in `Dynamic` has to be generated from an image anyway, so you still have to waste the memory for the original image. But then it becomes clear that we could just do `Dynamic[Refresh[Import["image.jpg"], None]]` with `image.jpg` nicely compressed somewhere on the hard drive. All one needs to insure is that you load from the correct directory. That actually works very well.

Comment: That last one with Import is a nice idea. The other one has the extra that it stores everything in the notebook. And you only need the image when you run, e.g, `With[{string2=ExportString[ExportString[<<img>>, "GIF"], "Base64"]}, Dynamic[Refresh[ImportString[string2, "Base64"], None]]]`. After you run that, you can delete your original image and stick with the output, right?

Comment: In any case, the Import["image seems to be very interesting indeed. I don't think you need to keep the cell or make it an initialization cell

Comment: @Rojo Yes, your suggestion with `ImportString` does indeed reduce the file size of the notebook significantly once I delete the original image. With my test photo of 900kB I get the size of the notebook down to 5MB from 11MB! But with the `Import` of the external image I end up with a total size of 900kB because the notebook is essentially zero size!

Comment: Cool. This should be MMA tip of the day

Comment: @Rojo They just had Compress as tip of the day... Now we're saying "forget Compress"! Nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you open a cell containing a photo with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, you'll see something like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, internally there's already something compressed going on. Problem is, Mathematica uses a compression schema where the end result only contains printable characters, so this is slightly less efficient than a fully binary format.

I don't think Mathematica offers the possibility of an indexed color space.

[[torn paper by Heike]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/57)

Comment: I guess that was devised so you can transfer the .nb by using [Baudot encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code)

Comment: @belisarius Don't think so, as Baudot coding doesn't use lowercase characters.

Comment: @belisarius It's amusing to compare the outputs of `string1=Compress["Hello"]` and `string2=ExportString["Hello", "Base64"]`. The compressed `string2` is a quarter the length than what Wolfram uses in `string1`... Why didn't they go with base64 encoding?

Comment: @Jens Try the string "HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHello" instead and you see Compress takes much less space. Compression of small files isn't normally efficient.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Almost: _Extended baudot allows the transmission and reception of the full ASCII character set while retaining 100% compatibility with standard baudot decoders._  http://reocities.com/siliconvalley/heights/4477/btlhelp.txt

Comment: The trend I see is still that `Compress` compares unfavorably with `Base64` encoding, see my edited answer.

Comment: @Jens I agree. Checked it for all standard test images and some large jpegs.

Comment: Base64 is *not* a compression scheme. It is an encoding scheme to ensure that output is within readable ASCII characters (by grouping three 8 bits to four 7 bits)--to avoid escape chars and high-bit chars. You can see it all the time in usenet binary groups (since it only serves pure texts). Compress[] already returns a result in Base64. You can roughly think Compress[] as ExportString[ExportString[..., "GZIP"], "Base64"] (roughly...).

Comment: Base64 results are always larger than the original (every 3 bytes will turn into 4bytes, so roughly 4 Quotient[original_size, 3]).