# Tool to locate bloat in a notebook?

Tags: graphics, notebooks, files-and-directories

In developing a notebook, I often find I have created a very boated file that takes a long time to save. I would like to slim it down. It is usually the result of graphics and images, but they may be hidden deep in the hierarchy of the notebook. Finding the wasted space is a pain. A very useful tool would be something that graphically indicated (perhaps in the cell marker) the number of bytes (or similar) that are within a cell.
Anyone know of such a thing, or have a pointer on how to create?

Comment: Nice idea, seems totally doable

Comment: You could automate conversion of all images to bitmap.

Comment: I asked WRI if it's possible to toggle the front end to display graphic output and the output of ancillary (exploratory) code in a separate notebook on a per-cell basis, but the reply I got didn't sound promising.

Comment: **Top Menu: Cell >> Delete All output** - saves a lot of space for notebooks with a lot of graphics.

Comment: In addition to @VitaliyKaurov: programmatically delete certain cells (here Output): `NotebookFind[
 SelectedNotebook[], "Output", All, CellStyle]; NotebookDelete[
 SelectedNotebook[]]`

Comment: As kguler's answer suggested, maybe you can use `ByteCount` to scan every output cell and generate a statistical chart or something you like. And I love your idea:)

Comment: I'm thinking tha a palette to store the output that weights a lot in external files and load them with `Dynamic` would be nice

Comment: @Rojo Maybe something like the notebook history palette?

Comment: @Silvia, I was thinking of a palette to implement what's said in the edit 2 forward of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6159/109) (and the comments and other answers too). A palette to handle the importing and exporting of resources in and out of the notebook

Comment: @Rojo Sounds nice! Just like what html does

Answer (score 12):

Maybe, displaying the bytecount of every output expression in tooltips or status area:

```
$Post = Tooltip[#, ByteCount[#]] &
```

or

```
$Post = StatusArea[#, ByteCount[#]] &
```

To delete all generated cells in the notebook, evaluate

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]
```

or

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["DeleteGeneratedCells"]
```

To delete all generated cells upon closing a notebook, you can use

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :>   FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}];
```

inside the notebook.

Or, you can select `Selected Notebook` or `Global Preferences` in the `Options Inspector` and add

```
{"WindowClose" :>  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}
```

to the `NotebookEventActions` line.

Comment: kguler, this piqued my curiosity. This may be a good way for me to avoid my earlier problem (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47805/9150). But I'd prefer never to save the output cells, even when I save without closing the notebook. I couldn't find an event like `SaveNotebook` with which I could adopt this solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that it wouldn't be useful if the output cells disappeared from the notebook every time it was saved. What I'm proposing is making the output cells more ephemeral, sort-of like a kernel.

Comment: @RicoPicone, something like `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  NotebookEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", "Save"} :>     FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}];`?

Comment: Yes, that works to delete the output cells on save (thanks), but, as I feared, it deletes them from the immediate view of the notebook. I'd prefer it if the output remained in the immediate view of the notebook even when it was saved and its output cells deleted in the saved version. I realize this might be very hard to do. I want a "working copy" that saves (sans output) to the "disk copy," but without losing the output in the "working copy." This is probably pretty easy if the "working copy" is a *different file* than the "disk copy," but I don't know how to do it if its the same file.

Comment: Should I make this a new question? It's so related to this question that I feared it would be marked a duplicate.

Comment: @RicoPicone, a new question is a good idea. You can link to this Q/A and mention why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I finally decided to try using this for the event `"WindowClose"`. However, it crashes my Mathematica (v 9.0.1.0, Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit kernel)). The notebook closes, *then* a dialog box asks me if I really want to delete the generated cells. If I say "yes," it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pico, it worked ok on my Windows 8 system with Version 9.0.1.0.

Comment: Interesting. Ah, well. Maybe it'll work for the next version on OS X.

Comment: @kglr Hi, kglr. I can't see anything different after running `$Post = StatusArea[#, ByteCount[#]] &`, but the tooltip works. I am using MMA 10.4.1

Comment: Hi @matheorem, i still use version 9. Not sure how to fix it to make it  work in version 10.

Comment: @kglr Oops, I was looking at the wrong place. `StatusArea` also works. Thanks