# “automated” image embedding app

Tags: notebooks, image

Based on the [following](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/how-to-place-an-image-inside-a-notebook-with-the-minimum-memory-footprint) image attach procedure, can a `Dynamic` app be developed that:

1. at start, only shows a small import button
2. once clicked, opens a choose image file dialog
3. after the image file chosen by the user, asks for representation
   dimension (pixels or percentage of the screen, etc), some other
   stuff possible: type and degree of compression (native, JPG, etc), frame, tear down effect etc
4. after options chosen, removes the button and replaces it with the low
   footprint image following the chosen options
5. right click on the image, and we can choose two "empty" the space (to restart the process)

Actually, there should be two import buttons: one for a file dialog, and another for importing from the clipboard (very useful when used with a screen snag tool).

An output cell with this dynamic app could then be easily duplicated and past to different notebooks, in order to facilitate the procedure of the above referenced post.

Comment: Isn't a palette a better fit for that kind of functionality?

Comment: @belisarius you are probably right. Either way, the end result is a `Dynamic` cell that, with very little extra footprint, can include the needed code to change/update itself (the same code that would be added on the palette). This means no palette distribution needed for other editors of the same document.