# How to reduce notebook or CDF file size with many images in it?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

We love to use Mathematica notebooks to keep our notes, so we import lot of scanned photos into notebooks.

However, the nb file size goes crazy large after importing photos in it.

For example, importing a 630KB jpg photo is going to produce a 13MB nb file.

We tried to save it as CDF or other format, but no luck. Both .nb and .cdf files are in ASCII text format, and that's why the file size grows so crazy.

Does anyone knows about any possible solutions to reduce the file size?

Comment: I couldn't add a comment at the time, but now I can. Maybe this question would help you? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/how-to-place-an-image-inside-a-notebook-with-the-minimum-memory-footprint

That said, importing LOTS of scanned photos may cause you problems. Try the solutions suggested in the link above. If that doesn't work well enough for you, perhaps because the imported files are too big, then another approach such as compressing your scanned photos beforehand as much as possible might be necessary.

Alternatively, Mathematica might not be the tool for you!

Comment: @blochwave there you go: you got enough rep now :D

Comment: Thanks, clears up any confusion over whether my "answer" was an "answer" or not!

Comment: @blochwave we are most definitely looking forward to your upcoming (totally answer-ish) answers!