# Is there a way to use iframes in a notebook?

Tags: import, notebooks, animation, html

For me, mathematica online is totally unusable, but the EmbeddedServices would be great to use. I wish that these functions worked in Mathematica, is there any hack anyone can think of to get these working?

[image]

Comment: The closest (that I know of) to what you're asking is that you can embed a movie from the web in a `Dynamic` cell, as I do here in edit 3 of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6159/245). However, it only works if you have the URL of the actual movie data.