# Is there a way to store and display compressed videos within a Mathematica notebook/CDF?

Tags: video

I know how to import videos into Mathematica using the `FFmpeg` [package](https://github.com/kmisiunas/ffmpeg-mathematica) (Mathematica's built-in import for AVIs rarely ever works for me or anyone, since Mathematica is usually missing the right codecs), and I can then play the videos using ListAnimate. The problem is, when I do that, video compression is lost, and the notebooks become gigantic: For the particular example I am currently working on, I have a .wmf video that's roughly 35MB, but when I import that into Mathematica I end up with a notebook file that's about 775MB. Is there a way to import and animate compressed video formats in Mathematica?

Mind you, the main application I have in mind right now is importing and displaying videos in, say, a Mathematica slideshow, the way I can do that in PowerPoint. I'm not interested in saving compressed video externally, unless Mathematica would be able to load and display such videos directly.

Finally, ideally I would like to display just the running videos, with no control elements whatsoever. I haven't figured out how to do this, however. I can display a hide button with the `AppearanceElements -> "HideControlsButton"` option, but if I hide the controls then the video stops running. `AppearanceElements->None` on the other hand seems to have no effect.

Comment: *"I'm not interested in saving compressed video externally, unless Mathematica would be able to load and display such videos directly."* - but you've already said that you can load the video with ffmpeg and display with ListAnimate. Why not do that? Why do you need to save the movie data inside the notebook?

Comment: @Simon Woods It looks like once you have read in the video frames they will be stored in the notebook. Even if that was not the case, reading in the video frames on demand is far, far too slow to be practical. The issue is that when Mathematica loads the video frames, they get decompressed, which is the reason for the substantial increase in size.

Comment: Yes, this seems possible. For your first problem, you could read the file as binary data (not import it and uncompress it). You can include this data directly inside your dynamic cell. When you want to watch the video, you can convert the binary data to images as you would do with `Import` and display the animation. For your second problem, the most painless way is probably to just write the few lines of code that display a list of images with a fixed delay. You don't really need `ListAnimate` for this.

Comment: With this approach, you have your videos compressed in the notebook and the notebook is small on disk. When you make your presentation, then of course the uncompressed versions are required and your RAM will contain the memory for the images.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see what you are suggesting. However, then the problem arises as to how I can process the object I have read into Mathematica as binary data. My guess is that this would require either writing a video decoder in Mathematica myself (out of the question, I know nothing about video decoding), or somehow integrating the available ffmpeg source code via some clever MathLink programming, which I am also not competent to do.

Comment: Re loading from external file, is it necessary to read individual frames on demand? Why not load the whole movie file in one go, then display?

Comment: [How to place an image inside a notebook, with the minimum memory footprint?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6157/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run on Windows you could use [MathMF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46813/862) for this. In the example below the video frames are loaded on demand and displayed using `Monitor`.

```
Needs["MathMF`"]

playmovie[filename_] := Catch @ Module[{t0, image},
   Check[MFInitSourceReader[filename], Throw[$Failed]];
   t0 = AbsoluteTime[];
   While[image =!= EndOfFile,
     Pause[Max[MFSourceTime[] + t0 - AbsoluteTime[], 0]];
     image = MFGrabFrame["ByteImage"]
     ] ~Monitor~ image]

playmovie["20130703_141431.mp4"] 
(* movie appears here *)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hah, this does what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I quickly looked through the `FFmpeg` package. It seems it only works on files. However, since it basically uses a system call to `ffmpeg` to retrieve the frames, I'm sure this can be adapted so that you can feed the binary data instead of a file to this call.

That being said, I'm going to show how you can include the binary data inside a `DynamicModule` to make it self-contained. As example, I'm going to use a png image:

```
inlinedBinaryImage[path_] := Module[{data},
  data = Import[path, {"Text", "String"}];
  With[{d = data},
   DynamicModule[{img = "Please Click to decompress image"},
    Panel@ClickPane[
      Dynamic[img],
      Function[Null,
       img = ImportString[d, "PNG"]]
      ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

With this function, you can load and store the compressed png file inside and when you click on the pane, it is decompressed with `ImportString`. In your real application, you need to replace the `ImportString` call with whatever function decodes your video data.

```
inlinedBinaryImage["~/tmp/test.png"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and when you click, the image is reconstructed

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's an interesting approach, too. This way I could "embed" the compressed video in the notebook file so have everything I need in a self-contained file.