# Iconize a compressed image

Tags: image-processing, import, compression

I want to embed a compressed image in a notebook so that only an icon is visible (and not the whole image).

The following procedure seems to work :

```
ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}] // ExportString[#, "JPG"] & // 
 Iconize[#, "lena 00 compressed"] &
```

[image]

One can copy-paste the icon above in the following code and evaluate it.
Then the image is retrieved.

```
ImportString["paste the icon here","JPG"]
```

[image]

[image]

**The problem**

If I quit, reopen and evaluate only the cell with `ImportString[...`, it doesn't work anymore.

[image]

Any solution/workaround for this problem ?

Notes :

- My real aim is to embed a video as a *list of 200 compressed images* under a simple icon. The compression is necessary because of [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138652/5467). Morever, I need to retrieve a list of *independently* compressed images in order to `Manipulate[]` them with good reactivity (forward and backward. The decompression, which  is quick, is made on the fly)
- I have tried without success to replace `Iconize[...]` by some code with `Interpretation[...]`.

Mathematica 11.3 Windows 7 (64bits)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

@andre mentions that an alternative to the two step procedures in my original answer is to convert the image to a byte array directly using `ExportByteArray`. So:

```
Iconize[
    ExportByteArray[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPG"],
    "lena 00 compressed"
]
```

[image]

[image]

**Original answer**

I don't know what the issue is (perhaps a character encoding issue), and it would be worth reporting it to support. As a workaround, you can also compress the string:

```
Iconize[
    Compress @ ExportString[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPG"],
    "lena 00 compressed"
]
```

[image]

[image]

The import still works after quiting and reopening.

**Addendum**

Probably a better approach is to convert to a [`ByteArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ByteArray) instead of a compressed string, since the JPEG is already compressed. The byte array will be smaller and faster to convert back to the JPG string.

```
Iconize[
    StringToByteArray @ ExportString[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPG"],
    "lena 00 compressed"
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @andre I would think so.  Maybe make it clear this is simply you reporting a bug and not needed "help" per se.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I have investigated in another direction and I finally discovered `ExportByteArray[...,"JPG"]` and `ImportByteArray[...,"JPG"]` which seem to be better in all points of view. Do I post a answer or do you prefer to complete yours ?