# Finding long strings of identical digits in transcendental numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, number-theory

#### Introduction

Describing the three main streams of present-day mathematical philosophy (formalism, Platonism and intuitionism) in a well-known book, [The Emperor's New Mind](http://www.google.pl/books?id=oI0grArWHUMC&pg=PA129&hl=pl&source=gbs_toc_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), R. Penrose says:

> ...it will perhaps be helpful if I refer to just a few of the problems. An example often referred to by Brouwer concerns the decimal expansion of 
>   $\pi = 3.141592653589793...$
>
> Does there exists a succession of twenty consecutive sevens somewhere in this expansion, i.e.
>   $$\pi = 3.141592653589793...77777777777777777777...$$
>   or does there not ?
>
> In ordinary mathematical terms, all that we can say, as of now, is that either there does or there does not—and we do not know which! This would seem to be a harmless enough statement. However, the intuitionists would actually deny that one can validly say "either there exists a succession of twenty consecutive sevens somewhere in the decimal expansion of $\pi$, or else there does not"—unless and until one has (in some constructive way acceptable to the intuitionists) either established that there is indeed such a succession, or else established that there is none! A direct calculation could suffice to show that a succession of twenty consecutive sevens actually does exist somewhere in the decimal expansion of $\pi$, but some sort of mathematical theorem would be needed to establish that there is no such succession. No computer has yet proceeded far enough in the computation of $\pi$ to determine that there is indeed such a succession. One's expectation on probabilistic grounds would be that such a succession does actually exist, but even if the computer were to produce digits consistently at the rate of, say, $10^{10}$ per second, it would be likely to take something of the order of between one hundred and one thousand years to find the sequence!

#### The actual problem

Since the above seems rather a bit beyond the scope of average computers I would like to find every sequence of length at least 10 of consecutive identical digits in the first $10^{9}$ digits of the decimal expansion of $\pi$. The solution would be better if it could be easily extensible to a multiple of $10^{9}$ digits, say the first $10^{10}$ digits of $\pi$.

We shouldn't restrict to the decimal digits of $\pi$, but preferable solutions should work with any finite numbers of digits any transcendental numbers, e.g. $e^\pi, {\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 3}$, etc.

Techniques like parallelization, compilation, GPU support etc. are acceptable to achive any possibly efficient solutions.

#### A step by step method not fulfilling expectations

In case of $\pi$ we could e.g. try something like a "step by step" approach:

```
l2 = Split[ First @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000000, -20000000]];
Position[ Length /@ l2, Max @ (Length /@ l2)]
l2[[#]] & /@ Flatten @ %
(* {{4193044}}
{{7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7}} *)
```

and

```
l4 = Split[ First @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000000, -40000000]];
Position[ Length /@ l4, Max @ (Length /@ l4)]
l4[[#]] & /@ Flatten @ %
(* {{5113613}, {5996894}}
{{6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}, {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8}} *)
```

Here we found only succsessions of length `9`, so it is not exactly what I wanted but it helps to understand why this method suffers from time and memory problems, often yielding

```
No more memory available.
Mathematica kernel has shut down.
Try quitting other applications and then retry.
```

A "step by step" is too time-consuming because Mathematica needs to compute first decimal digits every time we want to proceed to the next step and the access time depends roughly linearly on number of steps, e.g. :

```
tunit = First[ Split[ First @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 1000, -10000]]; // AbsoluteTiming];
timeT = 1/tunit Table[ First @ AbsoluteTiming[ Split[ First @ RealDigits[Pi, 10, 1000, -6000k]];],
                      {k, 60}];
ListLinePlot[timeT]
```

[image]

Maybe some `Reap` and `Sow` approach or whatever else?

Comment: Interesting question. After numbers of Pi are given the search for the repeat-sequence should be easily parallelizable due to complete independence of search for non-overlapping digit sub-sequences of Pi. Estimates on lower bound of computational time for an average machine or GPU could be useful.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks. We need some performance-tuning more in case of digit searching functions (like `RealDigits`), since it takes much more time. On the other hand, we should assume that we cannot (in general) keep in `RAM` `10^9` digits.

Comment: I wonder if someone could leverage a spigot algorithm for this...

Comment: A very good question but the title is quite abstract and perhaps should be more specific.

Comment: Change the name of Mma to another product in this question and it still makes sense. Now, ask: Is this is Mathematica specific question?

Comment: @faleichik Thank You !  I agree that title can be changed, but so far I haven't found none of brief and informative ones, so I am open for constructive suggestions.

Comment: @ndroock1 Step by step method is just a specific "solution" in Mathematica. My question is whether I could expect some refinement of methods based on mastering `RealDigits`, or else should I look for a completely different approach ? I find it is obvious from the text and need not to be specified anymore. So I have to emphasize : This is a specific question to the Mathematica community!

Comment: @Artes How about "Detecting consecutive digits in the decimal expansion of pi?"

Comment: @faleichik Thanks for a nice suggestion. I think it should be underlined that one looks for identical consecutive digits. I'll wait a bit if there are the other ones.

Comment: Re spigots, the classic is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe_formula, may be worth taking a look since it's able to produce limited numbers of digits from the middle of the sequence, potentially mitigating memory exhaustion.  Perhaps could enable a moving-window-style solution?

Comment: [This question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740033/is-there-an-equivalent-of-stringposition-for-searching-lists-if-not-whats-t) was motivated by something similar.

Comment: Seems like BBP was part of MMA: http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/explorer/RefGuide/DigitExtractor.html

Answer (score 13):

While we wait for an MMA implementation of BBP formula to generate the digits of `Pi`, we can use published results to identify repeated digits and their locations. Searching through the one billion digits of `Pi` in the file [pi-billion.txt](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/pi/), in chunks of 10 million digits, with built-in function `StringPosition`:

```
(patterns = Table[Table[i - 1, {9}], {i, 10}];
strngpatterns = FromCharacterCode[48 + #] & /@ patterns;
positions = {};
ii = 0;
strm = OpenRead["... download directory ...\\ pi-billion.txt"];
While[ii < 99,
(* start from 10,000,000th digit and take chunks of 10,000,010 digits.*) 
(* Reset the current stream position 10 digits back to account for patterns that might fall on chunk boundaries*)
begin = 10000000 + ii*10000000 - If[ii == 0, 0, 10];
SetStreamPosition[strm, begin];
digitslist = StringJoin@Read[strm, ConstantArray[Character, {10000010}]];
positions = Join[positions, {{{begin}, 
    MapIndexed[{#2 - 1, #1} &, 
      StringPosition[digitslist, #] & /@ strngpatterns] // 
     Select[#, (#[[2]] != {}) &] &}}];
ii++;]
Close[strm];
positions) // AbsoluteTiming
```

after about 10+ minutes (Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9600 2.80GHz, 8GB RAM on Windows Vista 64-bitOS, MMA V 8.0.4.0), we get

[image]

(Torn-edge image thanks to [Heike's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/125))

Clean up the output and calculate the actual positions (subtract 1 to account for the decimal point):

```
{#[[2, 1 ;;, 1]], Flatten[#[[1, 1]] - 2 + #[[2, 1 ;;, 2 ;; -1]], 2]} & /@ 
  Pick[positions, (Last@# != {}) & /@ positions] // Grid
```

[image]

Since `StringPosition`, by default, includes overlaps, we can conclude

- 6 is the only digit that appears 10 times in a row in the first one billion digits of `Pi` in positions (386,980,412 - 386,980,421)
- No digits appear 11 or more consecutive positions.
- Digits `1,6,7,8,9` appear 9 consecutive positions in various places.

**Notes:**

- The source file is quite large and takes considerable time to download. Make sure to verify that MD5 checksum  provided on the website matches MD5 hash for the downloaded file.

That is, check that the following yields `True`:

```
 "3901670f41a84174103bd6a8f07651c0" ==
  IntegerString[FileHash["... your download directory ...\\pi-billion.txt", "MD5"], 16, 32]
```

- Files containing 10,000,000,000,050 decimal digits of `Pi` are available for download at [Alexander Yee`s website](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Pi/#Download)  (Thanks to @chris for the link.)

Comment: It might be possible to use this technique with these files? http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Pi/#Download

Comment: @chris, I was hoping we could find the link to these files. (The second link on the MIT page to Kondo's website was broken). Thank you.

Comment: @kguler Thanks for your support +1. Nevertheless I am a bit dissapointed that so far no one suggested a self-sufficient solution which one could easily apply for other transcendental numbers. Moreover we would benefit from the technique.

Comment: @Artes, thank you for the upvote. Judging from the comments on your question, I would not be surprised if someone is already working on a solution.