# How do I get a list of digits for a number?

Tags: numerics

I have this 200 digit number where I want to get the `IntegerDigits`, but the decimal point is in the way.

```
5.9786377666105440959755656271823065138015646836250389374946790881539\
  7157216930920631092404062126177741432101097347028242720848122219396854\
  08452395344964186804
```

What do I need to do to strip the decimal point to get a list of the digits?

Comment: Do you know `RealDigits` ?

Comment: Artes, I'm new around here so please forgive the question but why didn't you simply put that as an answer? Is there a preference for comments rather than answers?

Comment: @WalkingRandomly, No you are completely right but sometimes (*older*) member just give a short comment, because they don't need the reputation.

Comment: @WalkingRandomly I think this question is appropriate for users with lower reputation. If you are interested in some more advanced problems with `RelaDigits` look at this question : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/finding-long-strings-of-identical-digits-in-transcendental-numbers

Comment: I understand, very public spirited of you.  At the moment, however, I need all the rep I can get around here so appreciate you standing aside and letting me getting an easy answer in :)

Comment: @WalkingRandomly Well, this is not pure altruism, I believe. I think most high-rep users would agree that we need as many skilled M users to quickly get the rep. and associated privileges, as possible, to help manage our fast-growing community. In some sense, our survival as a community (preserving its culture, purpose, ways of communications etc) crucially depends on this, in the long-term at least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are looking for is the function `RealDigits`

```
RealDigits[5.978637766610544095975565627][[1]]
```

It should give you the functionality you need.

Comment: I edited you answer to make the inline-code into a code-block which is better readable. Furthermore, you don't need to give the full number IMO. A smaller one which fits on the line is sufficient to show the usage.

Comment: And btw, if you answered the question it kind of suggests, that you find the question OK. Therefore, upvote it. You should read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq) and maybe join the [chat for smalltalk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica). And finally, welcome! Nice to have you here.

Comment: thanks for that, such gentle corrections are a nice way to learn how best to be a good SE citizen.