# Count consecutive occurrences in a list above a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to tally and sort the number of consecutive occurrences in a list above a certain value.

For instance:

```
data={55.5, 65.3, 100.3, 100.1, 100.5, 98.7, 75.2, 101.3, 102.1}
```

The totals for this data set would be {3,2} if the tally criteria were all values greater than 100.

As I have worked on this problem, I found the following code:

```
a = RandomInteger[1, {100}];
Cases[Split[a], {1, ___}] // Tally // Sort
```

Which is very close to what I am trying to do.  In this case, the code provides a sorted list of consecutive integers equal to one.

However, I can't seem to modify the decision criteria to only tally values above a certain criteria.

How might I go about this?

Comment: This question is closely related: [Finding long strings of identical digits in transcendental numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/finding-long-strings-of-identical-digits-in-transcendental-numbers), unfortunately I haven't got so far a quite satisfactory answer.

Comment: This works but it will not be efficient for huge data: `(Total /@ Split@(Boole[# > 100] & /@ data)) /. (0 -> Sequence[])`

Comment: Do you count a single appearance of a number >100?  e.g. `{. . . , 3, 7, 108, 2, 14, . . .}`?

Answer (score 8):

*Edit: there is an ambiguity in the question (and my answer) as to whether or not you want to include single-element "runs" in your tally.*

---

If you merely want to *count* the elements in each run and not also return the elements I propose:

```
Cases[Split @ UnitStep[100 - data], x : {0, __} :> Length@x]
```

> ```
> {3, 2}
> ```

If you (also) want to return the elements you could use this:

```
Module[{us = UnitStep[100 - data], tally},
 tally = Cases[Split[us], x : {0, ___} :> Length@x];
 dynamicPartition[Pick[data, us, 0], tally]
]
```

> ```
> {{100.3, 100.1, 100.5}, {101.3, 102.1}}
> ```

You'll need my `dynamicPartition` function described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/121).

---

### Timings

Comparing my proposal to rm-rf's:

```
data = RandomReal[200, 750000];

Cases[Split@UnitStep[100 - data], x : {0, __} :> Length@x]        // Length // Timing

Length /@ Split[data, # > 100 && #2 > 100 &] /. 1 -> Sequence[]   // Length // Timing

Select[Total[Split@Clip[data, {100, 100}, {0, 1}], {2}], # > 1 &] // Length // Timing
```

> {0.109, 93479}
>
> {0.671, 93479}
>
> {0.655, 93479}

Answer (score 7):

One direct way is to use the second argument of `Split` and find sublists of length > 0:

```
Length /@ Split[data, # > 100 && #2 > 100 &] /. 1 -> Sequence[]
```

or by clipping the values before splitting:

```
Select[Total[Split@Clip[data, {100, 100}, {0, 1}], {2}], # > 1 &]
```

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about the efficiency but how about defining a test function:

```
testFunction = (# > 100 &)
```

and then

```
Length /@ Select[Split[testFunction /@ data], First]
```

or if you don't want singletons

```
Length /@ Cases[Split[testFunction /@ data], {True, __}]
```

Comment: This does not give output that matches mine or rm-rf's; please check it.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure about the meaning of "consecutive occurrences" -- yours takes one interpretation, mine takes another.  Clarification is needed.

Comment: No, you're correct, mine reports "runs" of length one which probably aren't wanted.

Comment: I'm not so sure; the code in the question includes `___` (`BlankNullSequence`) which would match *your* interpretation.  It's not clear IMHO.  By the way, `Thread` should be a least slightly faster: `Length /@ Select[Split[Thread[data > 100]], First]`

Comment: I've added an alternative that excludes singletons, using `Cases`, but still no `Thread` -- using the test function means it could be written as a generic `RunLengths[data,test]` function.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is general and fast, allowing the use of any predicate (not just ones based on a numerical threshold) and using the fact that you'll have alternating runs of elements that satisfy the predicate and elements that **don't** satisfy the predicate:

```
runLengths[list_, pred_] :=
 With[{bits = Boole[pred@#] & /@ list},
  Length /@ Part[
    Split[bits],
    If[bits[[1]] == 0,
     Span[2, All, 2],
      Span[1, All, 2]]]]
```

**EDIT** to add: Some timings:

```
bigData = RandomReal[{0, 200}, {10000}];

Do[runLengths[bigData, # >= 100 &], {100}] // Timing
```

> {0.218401, Null}

For comparison, here's Mr. Wizard's approach on my machine:

```
Do[
  Cases[Split@UnitStep[100 - bigData], x : {0, __} :> Length@x],
  {100}] // Timing
```

> {0.249602, Null}

So it's a little faster, and a little more flexible.

**EDIT** again to add:

I'm assuming we want to keep runs of length 1; those can always be deleted later in any event.

**EDIT** the third: just getting rid of `1` at the end adds very little overhead:

```
Do[DeleteCases[
   runLengths[bigData, # >= 100 &], 1], 
   {100}] // Timing
```

> {0.234002, Null}

Comment: Strange, using your own code my method is much faster.  I am getting `{0.78, Null}` and `{0.156, Null}` for the two outputs.  Version differences I guess?  Also, your method includes "singletons" which may or may not be desired; can your solution be adapted to eliminate these if required?

Comment: Could be version or even architecture variations. FWIW, I'm using Mathematica 9.0.1.

Comment: I have no reason to doubt your timings and you addressed the one concern. +1

Answer (score 5):

*As Mr. Wizard pointed out in the comments, my original code tests for elements greater or equal 100, a corrected version is in the edit below.*

I interpreted the question to include singletons and came up with the following, which I think performs decently

```
Length/@DeleteCases[Split[UnitStep[data-100]],{0..}]
```

**Edit**

The following tests for elements *greater* than 100

```
Length/@DeleteCases[Split[UnitStep[100-data]],{1..}]
```

Thanks to Mr. Wizard to pointing out mistakes and performance issues in this post!

Comment: I've got more critique, but please know I wouldn't bother except that I hope it helps.  You don't need to use `1 - Unitstep[. . .` as you can simply delete the 1's instead.  Also, your second method is inefficient as you pattern-match twice; it would be better to either use `Cases` as I did, or `Length /@ DeleteCases . . .` as you did in your first method.  If I were you I'd delete the second form of each one.  +1 for the corrected versions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard True again. Do you just want to take over this answer? :) Editing...

Comment: No, it looks perfect now. :^)

Answer (score 3):

Using [SequenceSplit](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceSplit.html) which came with V 11.3

```
Length /@ SequenceSplit[data, {x_ /; x < 100}]
```

{3, 2}

```
{Length /@ #, #} & [SequenceSplit[data, {x_ /; x < 100}]]
```

{{3, 2}, {{100.3, 100.1, 100.5}, {101.3, 102.1}}}

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers/140473#140473) to split by positions as follows:

```
Length /@ SequenceCases[Position[data, x_ /; x > 100], {__}?ConsecutiveQ]

(*{3, 2}*)

{Length@#, Extract[data, #]} & /@ 
SequenceCases[Position[data, x_ /; x > 100], {__}?ConsecutiveQ]

(*{{3, {100.3, 100.1, 100.5}}, {2, {101.3, 102.1}}}*)
```