# Selecting index position of data from a table that is less than a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table of numbers with a few thousand entries, and I'm trying to find the first index that is less than a particular value. An example of the table I'm working on is as follows:

```
dr = {6.34152*10^8, 6.32076*10^8, 6.29998*10^8, 6.27921*10^8, 6.25843*10^8, 6.23765*10^8, ...}
```

What I'm trying to do is find the first entry that is less than `5.77*10^8`. I've tried the following:

```
SOIdr = Position[dr, First[dr] < 5.77*10^8]
```

But have had no luck thus far. Any help would be appreciated, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is closely related to a number of others, if not an outright duplicate, but I can't find that duplicate now.  Your syntax for using `Position` is not correct.  You need something like this:

```
dr = {4, 7, 4, 8, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5};
val = 4;

Position[dr, x_ /; x < val, 1, 1]
```

> ```
> {{7}}
> ```

For numeric operations there are usually faster methods however.  I am looking for a Q&A that gives some examples.

---

Related: [Count consecutive occurrences in a list above a certain value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30362/121)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Wizard, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
dr = {4, 7, 4, 8, 8, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5};
val = 4;
Flatten@Position[Thread[Less[dr, val]], True]
{7}
```

Comment: Care to comment on how this approach differs (speed, efficiency, breadth, etc) from the currently accepted answer?

Comment: Under a very simple benchmark (1, 10, 100.. up to 1*10^6 repetitions), this answer has a smaller O(n) coefficient - 6.7s vs 9.1s for the worst case. But it finds all the smaller elements, not only the first.