# check a sequence in Pi

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, sequence

I read that the string `36541622473` occurs in `π`(pi) at position `36541622473`, counting from the first digit after the decimal point. So I want to check that with the code below. It runs but doesn't return anything.
What is wrong with it?

```
pi = Characters[ToString@N[Pi, 36541622473 + 20]];
pos = SequencePosition[pi, First[RealDigits[36541622473]]]
```

Update:
This is another code that I used but faced the same problem.

```
pi = N[Pi, 36541622473 + 20];
piList = First[RealDigits[pi]];
SequencePosition[piList, First[RealDigits[36541622473]]]
```

Comment: Does `RealDigits` return strings?  Isn’t your `pi` a list of character strings? Why not use `RealDigits` on `Pi`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I added an update the orignal code.

Comment: Why on earth would you expect a general use mathematical software system to return this in a time any less than hours of computation?

Easier just to download a dataset with the required range of digits and search that directly.

Comment: @ciao why does it finish running in several minutes?

Comment: @anhnha - I'd venture that "...it finniish..." is more like "...it quits the kernel..." due to memory exhaustion. This can look like it "...doesn't return anything."

Comment: it is interesting to ask how one could use Mathematica to generate the digits of $\pi$ this far without exhausting memory, though (even if it took a long time), which is essentially what this question is doing!

Comment: @thorimur exactly

Comment: @anhnha you need to use the [BPP formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) - but that will give you hex digits.

Comment: Related question: [Finding long strings of identical digits in transcendental numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/finding-long-strings-of-identical-digits-in-transcendental-numbers).

Comment: @thorimur : the fastest current decimal digit spigot-ish algorithm for Pi for specified digit positions with achievable resource requirements has ~O((n^2 log (log (n)))/log^2 (n)) run time.

On a reasonably fast machine, written in C, it still takes ~20 seconds to reach only out to the 10^5 digit range.

IOW: preposterous to use for magnitudes of the question at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
checkPi[n_] := 
  ToExpression[Import[StringJoin["https://api.pi.delivery/v1/pi?start=", 
       ToString@n, "&numberOfDigits=", ToString@IntegerLength@n]][[1, 
      2]]] == n;

checkPi@36541622473
```

> True

```
checkPi /@ {1, 16470, 44899, 79873884, 711939213, 36541622473, 
      45677255610, 62644957128, 656430109694}
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}

Comment: What to do if I'm looking for a sequence that starts with zero?

Comment: @Roman - by convention, these are not written in that form (you'd not answer the question "how far?" with "000005 km", yes?).

Comment: @ciao But I might want to search for the first occurrence of the sequence of digits `000005`

Comment: @rohitNamjoshi : that may well be so, but clearly that kind of search is not what the question is about.  In any case, the same code can trivially be changed to do naive search.