# Finding a subset in the set of the digits of Pi

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, dataset, subset, code

Well, I want to find the first position where the digits of Pi are `{a,b,c,...,z}`. So to find the first n digits of Pi and put them in listform I used:

```
IntegerDigits[Last[FoldList[FromDigits[{##}]&]@First@RealDigits@FractionalPart@N[Pi,n]]]
```

Now, I am stuck. How do find the positions where `{a,b,c,...,z}` occurs?

---

So as an example, when does `{7,9,3}` do appear for the first time in the digits of Pi? I know that it is at the 13th digit of Pi (checked by hand).

Comment: Starting with `SequencePosition[First@RealDigits@FractionalPart@N[Pi, 30], {7, 9, 3}, 1][[1, 1]]`, convert this to a function.

Comment: Google search came up with [this](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/core-language/find-a-sequence-in-the-digits-of-pi.html?product=mathematica).

Comment: try FirstPosition function

Comment: This is related closely [Finding long strings of identical digits in transcendental numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6323/finding-long-strings-of-identical-digits-in-transcendental-numbers).

Comment: You can achieve this by turning the problem into, appealing to the verification of the subset, this way if given a set just search through the sequence, if given a range and a set and asked if the set belongs in that range there's algorithm that can quickly find the number at a certain position, if a set is asked, just generate something random and say it really is a subset of the digits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's set up our parameters:

```
digitCount = 1000;
piDigits = First@RealDigits[N[Pi, digitCount]];
testSequence = {7, 9, 3};
```

You can now use SequencePosition:

```
SequencePosition[piDigits, testSequence]
```

`{{14, 16}, {440, 442}, {487, 489}}`

The first occurrence is at position 14 (the leading 3 is included in the digits--adjust as appropriate if you want to skip the leading 3).

Answer (score 2):

@BobHanlon 's point is very important. All these questions get additional value of you focus on making the switch from procedural programming to functional programming. So, I took the exercise. Turn Bob's answer to a function:

```
whereFirstInPiIs[x_List] := 
 SequencePosition[First@RealDigits@FractionalPart@N[Pi, 3000], x, 
   1][[1, 1]]
```

Now, it becomes trivial:

```
whereFirstInPiIs[{7, 9, 3}]
Out[...]= 13
```