# How to plot an inequality?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I need some help in plotting the following inequality using Mathematica:

$$\frac{1+(x/100+0.1)\times y/100}{1.15+1.15\times(x/100)\times(y/100)}\geq 1$$

assuming $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers and $5\leq x\leq 90,\ 50\leq y \leq 650$.

Copyable code for the above inequality:

```
(1 + (x/100 + 0.1)(y/100))/(1.15 + 1.15 (x/100)(y/100)) >= 1
```

I've tried the following in Maple (because it's what we had available) but it only simplifies the term and does not plot it and enclosing the inequality with `plot()` in Maple only generates errors.

```
assume(x, rational);
assume(y, rational);
assume(x>=5 and x<=90);
assume(y>=50 and y<=650);
(1+1*(x/100+0.1)*(y/100))/(1.15+1.15*(x/100)*(y/100))>=1;
```

#### Optional theoretical problem:

$x$ could theoretically (not in practice) be up to $100$, but $(x/100+0.1)$ on the left side would still always max out at $1$. Should the equation be changed to $x_1$ and $x_2$ with respective limits? But those limits would only apply for $x_1$ and $90< x_2 \leq 100$.

Comment: The "optional" part is not really a question for this site.

Answer (score 11):

Something like

```
RegionPlot[(1 + 1*(x/100 + 0.1)*(y/100))/(1.15 + 1.15*(x/100)*(y/100)) >= 1,
           {x, 5, 90}, {y, 50, 650}]
```

[image: kenshin's inequality]

might be what you need.

Answer (score 7):

You may also get the inequalities:

```
p = Reduce[(1 + 1*(x/100 + 1/10)*(y/100))/(115/100 + 115/100 (x/100) (y/100)) >= 1 &&
            x >= 5 <= 90 && y >= 50 <= 650, {x, y}]
(*
5 <= x < 200/3 && y >= -(30000/(-200 + 3 x))
*)
```

And then

```
Show[RegionPlot[p, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 700}], 
     Graphics[{Opacity[0.3], Red, Rectangle[{5, 50}, {90, 650}]}]]
```

[image]

Credit due to Heike [(the torn image function)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/torn-edge-paper-effect-for-images/4155#4155)

Comment: Interesting how `Opacity[]` makes the triangulation of the region apparent...

Comment: @J.M. Now it doesn't :D

Comment: @Dr.belisarius thank you for introducing me to torn image function +1 o/c :)