# Working around behaviour of EdgeRenderingFunction

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, function-construction

One can make graphs

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}]
```

and one can generalize the input such that one labels edges

```
 GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, {2 -> 3, "my favorite edge"}, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5,  5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}]
```

Now in the Mathematica help for GraphPlot, under Options and then EdgeRenderingFunction one finds the example

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}, 
EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If [
 First[#2] == Last[#2], {Red, Arrow[#1]}, {GrayLevel[0.5], 
  Arrow[#1]}] &)]
```

I want to use this to change the color of edges according to their naming, i.e. if the edge says "my favorite edge", then that edge should be green.

Problem is that once I use EdgeRenderingFunction,

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, {2 -> 3, "my favorite edge"}, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}, 
EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If [
 First[#2] == Last[#2], {Red, Arrow[#1]}, {GrayLevel[0.5], 
  Arrow[#1]}] &)]
```

the data beyond "2 -> 3" gets ignored. How to solve this problem?

(I don't really have to use EdgeRenderingFunction to change the color, I just want more than just the names to point out some special edges.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not ignored — the edge label is given as the third argument to `EdgeRenderingFunction`. You can do something like the following:

```
color := If[# === "my favorite edge", Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.5]] &
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, {2 -> 3, "my favorite edge"}, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}, 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[First[#2] == Last[#2], {Red, Arrow[#1]}, {color[#3], Arrow[#1]}] &)]
```

[image]

It might have seemed that it was being ignored because the labels were not displayed. The reason for this is given in "Possible issues" under [`EdgeLabeling`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0puylioesi-bteczx):

> An explicit setting for `EdgeRenderingFunction` overrides the setting for `EdgeLabeling`

So in order to get the edge labels, you'll have to incorporate that also in your `EdgeRenderingFunction`. Here's an example:

```
label := If[#1 =!= None, Text[#1, #2]] &
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, {2 -> 3, "my favorite edge"}, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}, 
    EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[First[#2] == Last[#2], {Red, Arrow[#1]}, {GrayLevel[0.5], 
        Arrow[#1], label[#3, Mean@#1]}] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I really wanted both at the same time, here is what I end up with: *EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[#3 == "my favorite edge", {Green, Arrow[#1], 
     Text[Style[#3, Small, Black], Mean[#1]]}, {Gray, 
     Arrow[#1]}] &)*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, {2 -> 3, "my favorite edge"}, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 5 -> 5}, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y,  z}, (If[z == "my favorite edge", {Red, Arrow[x]}, , 
                                                    {GrayLevel[0.5], Arrow[x]}])]]
```

[image]

[torn[] credit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4155/193)