# How to plot a curve with border around the line?

Tags: plotting, options

This can be useful if the curve is passing over both dark and light backgrounds (like well-done subtitles in movies).

Comment: Could you maybe give a sample of what you're expecting to see in the answers?

Comment: A closely related question is [How can I make a 2D line plot with a drop shadow under the line?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3058/245)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could plot the curve twice, with two different styles:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.03], White], Black}]
```

[image]

Changing the background to gray:

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.03], White], Black}, 
     Background -> Gray]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Btw, when you add plots as images, you should try to export *png*-files from Mathematica because they don't suffer from the ringing artefacts at line borders.

Comment: @halirutan, Thanks for the tip. In this case I don't see any differences between jpeg and png though. I will stick to png in the future.

Comment: Fixed it. Really close to hard lines or sharp dark/bright changes you see clutter.

Comment: @halirutan: Thanks!

Comment: @MarkusRoellig, maybe add `CapForm["Round"]` to your `Directive` for a tidier appearance.

Answer (score 21):

Here is another approach, based on `Filling` option :

```
Plot[{Sin[x] - 0.02, Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.02}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Gray, Black, Gray}, 
      Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, Yellow}}]
```

[image]

One problem may appear here, namely if a given function has a big absolute value of the derivative, then the strip becomes too thin. We can avoid this by adding a factor depending on the absolute value of its derivative, e.g.

```
Plot[{Sin[x]-0.035(1 + Abs[Sin'[x]]), Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.035 (1 + Abs[Sin'[x]])}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Gray, Black, Gray},  Filling -> {1 -> {{3}, LightOrange}}]
```

[image]

For a more customized solution we can use also one of the wide range of `ColorSchemes` :

```
Plot[{Sin[x]-0.035 (1+ Abs[Sin'[x]]), Sin[x], Sin[x] +0.035 (1+ Abs[Sin'[x]])}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick, Thin},  ColorFunction -> "FruitPunchColors",  
      FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.1],  Filling -> {1 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[ 
    Table[  Plot[{Sin[x]- 0.035 (1+ Abs[Sin'[x]]), Sin[x], Sin[x]+ 0.035 (1+ Abs[Sin'[x]])},
                 {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thick, Thin}, 
                 ColorFunction -> i, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.05], Filling -> {1 -> {3}}], 
          {i, {"Rainbow", "BlueGreenYellow", "DeepSeaColors"}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

A minor tweak to Markus' method, you may find utility in `CapForm`:

```
Table[
  Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle ->
     {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[15], CapForm[c], White], 
      Directive[AbsoluteThickness[7], Blue]},
   ImageSize -> 400, PlotRangePadding -> 0.2, Frame -> True,
   Prolog -> 
    Inset[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}], 
        Scaled@{0.5, 0.5}, Automatic, Scaled@{1, 2}]
   ],
  {c, {"Butt", "Round", "Square"}}
] // Column
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 for the CapForm and the Background :) nice!

Answer (score 4):

A minor variation of Markus' method, applying the effect as a post process using `ReplaceAll`. Every `Line` in the graphics is replaced with two Lines: a thicker copy and the original. The key thing is to localise the additional directives to the extra `Line` by wrapping it in a list, so that subsequent primitives do not pick up the thickness and colour changes.

For plots with many curves this might be a more convenient approach than explicitly duplicating the plot functions.

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Yellow, White}, BaseStyle -> Thick] /. 
 l_Line :> {{Thickness[0.01], Black, CapForm["Round"], l}, l}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since V 13.3 there is [Haloing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Haloing.html):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> Haloing[White, 0, 8],
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image]