# Filling using colors rendered corresponding to the difference between two curves

Tags: graphics, color, filling

Suppose there are two curves `f1[x]` and `f2[x]`, and we want to fill the area between them using colors corresponding to the vaule of `f2[x]-f1[x]`, so that any filling line segemts with the same length will be rendered with same color. My question is, how can we do this using built-in commands like `Filling`, `FillingStyle` and `ColorFunction`, etc? A direct call of `ColorFunction` will not help because in specification

```
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, g[x,y]]
```

the `x` and `y` are refered always as the absoulate coordinates, however we need to refer to `y2-y1` in our case. I have not figured out how to get this done using pure function.

I can write a code doing this from sketch similiar to the idea suggested in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function), but such treatment is not universal... Besides, there is already such an example documented in Mathematica,

```
ListLinePlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 250]], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Axis]
```

which is actually a similar case to my question but with `f1[x]` always equal to zero. So I think there should be a solution using only built-in commands...

Furthermore, if there is indeed such a solution, then we can simply generalize the relation from merely `f2[x]-f1[x]` to more interesting forms.

Comment: Is it for data-type like ListPlot or analytic like Plot functions ?

Comment: @ Vitaliy Kaurov, I am thinking about Plot like functions. ListPlot case can be done easily by manually drawing the line segments and use Show to combine the plots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `f2[x] - f1[x]` in `ColorFunction`

```
f1[x_] := Sin[x];
f2[x_] := Cos[x]; 
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-1.5, 1.5}}][f2[x] - f1[x]]], 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Here `-1.5` and `1.5` are minimim and maximum values of difference, `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` prevent scaling of difference.

Update:

For `ListPlot` you can use `Interpolation` in `ColorFunction` with the same `InterpolationOrder`

```
u1 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 50]];
u2 = Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 50]];
io = 1;

ListLinePlot[{u1, u2}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {-5, 5}}][
  Interpolation[u2, InterpolationOrder -> io][x] - 
  Interpolation[u1, InterpolationOrder -> io][x]]], 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, InterpolationOrder -> io]
```

[image]

Comment: Good perspective! However the line segments with same length are not rendered with same color yet.

Comment: @saturasl There are positive and negative differences. In my example they have different color. `Abs[f1[x]-f2[x]]` will show absolute difference.

Comment: I see, very nice answer, thanks!