# Is it possible to vary the thickness of curves according to their color code

Tags: plotting

I have this data

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[5 x], Tanh[3 x]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.01}];
```

which I plot as follows

```
colorbar[reg_] := Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, Rescale[reg, {-1, 1}]]
ListLinePlot[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]],ColorFunction ->Function[{x, y}, 
   colorbar[data[[Position[data[[All, 1]], 
        Nearest[data[[All, 1]], x][[1]]][[1, 1]], 3]]]], 
 ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 0.6, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.02], CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
```

[image]

the curve has the `Thickness[0.02]`, my question is how can I assign a `Thickness[0.005]` for the black part of the curve and  `Thickness[0.02]` for other colors?

Comment: Please learn how to propose the *MINIMUM* question.  Do you need all those curves?  Of course not.  A single sine curve would suffice.  You'll get more help that way.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thanks! modified accordingly.

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [Vary the thickness of a plotted function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28202/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[variableWidthCurve, widthF, cF, crv]
variableWidthCurve[curve_, wf_][x_, u_] := curve[x] +
   (1 - 2 u) wf[x]/2 Cross@Normalize[curve'[x]];

widthF[func_, range_: {-1, 1}, minmaxthickness_: {.01, .1}][x_] := 
  Rescale[func[x], range, minmaxthickness];

cF = Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, Rescale[Tanh[3 #], {-1, 1}]] &;

crv[x_] := {x, Sin[5 x]}

ParametricPlot[variableWidthCurve[crv, widthF[Tanh[3 #] &]][x, u], 
 {x, -1, 1}, {u, 0, 1},
 ColorFunction -> cF, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.6, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Use `widthF[Abs[#] &, {0, 1}, {0.01, .1}]` to get:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is probably a better solution, but here is a brute force approach.

```
data=Table[{x,Sin[5 x],Tanh[3 x]},{x,-1,1,0.01}];
colorbar[reg_]:=Blend[{Blue,Black,Red},Rescale[reg,{-1,1}]]
```

Divide the data into 50 segments, overlapping by 1 point:

```
segments=50;
data2=Partition[data[[All,1;;2]],segments,1];
```

Define widths based on the Norm of the RGB value at the middle x-value of each segment:

```
width[x_]:=Directive[Thickness[Norm[Cases[InputForm[colorbar[x]],RGBColor[v___]:>v]]/30]]
widths=Table[width[s[[Round[segments/2],1]]],{s,data2}];

ListLinePlot[data2,ColorFunction->Function[{x},colorbar[x]],ImageSize->500,AspectRatio->0.6,ColorFunctionScaling->False,PlotStyle->widths,Axes->False,Frame->True,PlotRange->{-1,1}]
```

[image]