# How to get a Fountain Pen effect when Drawing Curves?

Tags: graphics, eventhandler

I am attempting to draw a curve where the width of the curve reduces with the speed at which I drag the mouse (a fountain pen effect).  The gif below demonstrates the desired functionality.

[image]

The code below allows me to draw a curve where the width does not change (ball point pen effect).  Any ideas?

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}, d = 1}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]}, Opacity[1], Red, 
     AbsoluteThickness[5], 
     BezierCurve@list}]], {"MouseDragged" :> (d = 1;
     AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]])}]]
```

Comment: Interesting question. Though I suspect this kind of stylish stroke might cause performance issue if it's done in full vector form (i.e. `Line`, `BSpline` and friends).

Comment: @Silvia makes sense.  I'll post this related link here just in case: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function