# How to produce wavy lines

Tags: graphics, generative-art

New to Mathematica, I'd like to produce some 'thick wavy lines' as simple graphical forms (not sure how else to describe them), like the waved shape of this dagger blade (but not the handle):

[image]

I've searched https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ > Art & Visual Patterns but couldn't find anything like that.

Are these shapes better off being created by other software?

The end result I'm after is to combine many of them to produce some splayed hair on a graphical portrait of a woman, something like this, in graphic form

[image]

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Here's a way to vary thickness of a line/curve (for the dagger): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28202/vary-the-thickness-of-a-plotted-function -- hair texture seems a big ask and a big step from the dagger shape. If you want a silhouette or cartoonish graphics, maybe there's a better image to emulate. Otherwise it seems like these should be separate questions.

Comment: *Are these shapes better off being created by other software?* -- I hope so. The dagger blade has simple mathematical expressions for modeling the silhouette. Likewise for the twisted-rope handle. These aren't too hard in Mma. (Sans textures.) The hilt will exhaust most persons' patience. The hair is another matter altogether, as I said earlier. The closest thing to hair texture is given by [`LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html), but I have no idea how to adapt it to hair that has overlaps etc.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I've updated my question for more clarity; I'd like to produce simpler graphical forms mimicking the dagger blade only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try e.g. BSplineCurve or BezierCurve. Here is an example using BSplineCurve:

First we create some control points:

```
pts0 = Table[{i, (-1)^i}, {i, -3, 3}]; pts0 = 
 Join[{{-4, 0}}, pts0, {{4, 0}}]

{{-4, 0}, {-3, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-1, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {2, 
  1}, {3, -1}, {4, 0}}
```

And then we create a Manipulate that lets you adapt the line to your needs:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {5 {-1, 1}, 2 {-1, 1}}], {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

And to export the graphis you could e.g. write:

```
Manipulate[gr=Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {5 {-1, 1}, 2 {-1, 1}}], {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]

Export["d:/tmp/export.jpg", gr]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. If I run `Export ["graphic", graphics, SVG]` or `Export ["graphic", graphics, GIF]` there is an error `Export::infer: Cannot infer format of file graphic.`

Comment: I added an example how to export.

Comment: Using the command `Export["c:\Temp\export.jpg", gr]` there was a message "assuming a file name" and the file `c:\Temp\export.jpg` contained a small 14px x 15px JPG containing the characters `gr`.

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong Manipulate that did not store the graphics.. The right is: `   Manipulate[gr=Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {5 {-1, 1}, 2 {-1, 1}}], {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]`. And then, the file name must be a name on your PC.
`

Comment: I've updated to `Manipulate[gr = Graphics[{Thickness[0.05], BSplineCurve[pts]}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {5 {-1, 1}, 2 {-1, 1}}], {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]}` and run `Export["c:\Temp\export.jpg", gr]` and receive a message `Assuming a file name | Use as a generic text string instead` & `c:\Temp\export.jpg` remains unchanged since 13/8/2023.

Comment: You need `Export["c:/Temp/export.jpg", gr]` not `Export["c:\Temp\export.jpg", gr]

Comment: Making that change made no difference. :) `c:\Temp\export.jpg` remains unchanged

Comment: MMA requires forward slashes, but Windows requires backward slashes. You did not change the backward slashes.

Comment: What I mean was I ran the command `Export["c:/Temp/export.jpg", gr]` but `c:\Temp\export.jpg` remains unchanged

Comment: Where do you see backwards slashes. I get an output with forward slashes. My version: 13.3 Windows 10

Comment: It's not the output in Mathematica `c:\Temp\export.jpg` that I am referring to, it is the file `c:\Temp\export.jpg` that I am referring to, which remains unchanged.

Comment: Did you export the graphics AFTER you changed the Manipulate?

Comment: No, doing so works, thanks, and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Would there be a way to export as an SVG with only the curve present in the file?

Comment: For this you need to save the points inside the manipulate, e.g.: `pts1 = pts;`  With these points,   you can create the curve alone by: `Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts1]}]`

Comment: Thanks, I receive an odd error https://i.imgur.com/5jpFi6u.png

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. `pts1 = pts;` needs to be inside the Manipulate, where pts is defined. As you write it, pts has no values. You can see this because "pts" is blue.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like my friend who was unable to locate the Start menu in Windows, sorry. I am unsure if a new manipulate function needs to be created or the original manipulate function modified. If the original needs to be modified, I am unsure where to place `pts1 = pts;`

Comment: You can use the original one. It does not matter much where you put it. E.g. Manipulate[pts1 = pts; ...]

Comment: [Still not following](https://i.imgur.com/KqOsOg8.png)

Comment: The following works for me (MMA version 13.3): `Manipulate[pts1 = pts; 
 Graphics[{BSplineCurve[pts]}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {5 {-1, 1}, 2 {-1, 1}}], {{pts, pts0}, Locator}]`

Comment: Yeah, I have MMA version 11.0, the same doesn't work on that version

Comment: You could try to put a Print statement inside manipulate to get at the data.

Answer (score 6):

## Plotting to Polygons

You can write equations to model curves.  Trig functions like `Sin` are typical for waves.  An envelope allows the wave to zigzag inside of another curve (in this case, something like the sword, $\sqrt x$).

```
Plot[{1.2 Sqrt[x], .8 Sqrt[x], -1.2 Sqrt[x], -.8 Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 50},
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {4}}](*envelopes*)
Plot[{
    Sqrt[x] {1.2, .8}.{Sin[x]^2, 1}, 
   -Sqrt[x] {1.2, .8}.{Sin[x + .5]^2, 1}}, {x, 0, 50}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}](*curves*)
(*instead of Plot, we'll use Table with an increment*)
(*we have to reverse the lower curve, going left along the top and right along the bottom*)
Graphics[{Polygon@Join[#[[1]], Reverse@#[[2]]]}] &@
  Transpose@Table[{
    {x, Sqrt[x] {1.2, .8}.{Sin[x]^2, 1}}, 
    {x, -Sqrt[x] {1.2, .8}.{Sin[x + .5]^2, 1}}}, 
 {x, 0, 50, .1}](*making into Graphics primitives*)
```

Experimenting with curves and parameters may be easier in Desmos.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It's possible to transform instances of Polygons and overlay them on images.  See [Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) for lots of examples.

Whatever you come up with, please post an answer along side this one.  We can iterate.

Answer (score 4):

### Procedure outline

1. Get an image with "wavy lines"
2. Import the image and extract edges representing the desired waves

   - `EdgeDetect` is used below.
3. Extract the coordinates of the image pixels of the points that represent the edges
4. Approximate the edges using a fitting function (of five)
5. Plot the approximations
6. Tune fitting parameters, goto step 4, or declare success

### Computation steps

Get the image:

```mathematica
imgDagger = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/izoS6.jpg"]
```

Remove the background:

```mathematica
img1 = RemoveBackground[imgDagger, "Salient"]
```

[image]

Binarize the image and take "the blade part" of it:

```mathematica
img2 = ImageTake[Binarize[img1, 0.09], All, {10, ImageDimensions[img1][[1]]*3/5}]
```

[image]

**Remark:** Applying `ColorNegate` seems appropriate, but we get good results without it.

Remove the black spots inside the blade:

```mathematica
img3 = Dilation[img2, 1.2]
```

[image]

Edge detect and dilate:

```mathematica
img4 = Dilation[EdgeDetect[img3], 1.2]
```

[image]

Extract the edge points and plot them:

```mathematica
lsPoints = Reverse /@ Position[ImageData[img4], 1, 2];
ListPlot[lsPoints]
```

[image]

Separate the extracted points (one set for each dagger edge):

```mathematica
lsPoints2 = GatherBy[lsPoints, #[[2]] > 115 &];
ListPlot[lsPoints2]
```

[image]

Using FindFormula would have been nice if it worked:

```mathematica
fm = FindFormula[lsPoints2[[1]], TargetFunctions -> {Sin, Cos, Times, Plus}]
```

[image]

```mathematica
ListPlot[fm /@ Range @@ MinMax[Append[lsPoints2[[2]][[All, 1]], 5]]]
```

We can use `Fit` and `NonLinearFit` but then we have to think about appropriate models. It is much easier to use the resource function [`QuantileRegression`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/QuantileRegression/). Here is an example:

```mathematica
qrFunc = First@ResourceFunction["QuantileRegression"][lsPoints2[[2]], 30, 0.5];
Show[ListPlot[lsPoints2[[2]], PlotStyle -> Gray], Plot[qrFunc[x], {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Let us introduce random noise into the dagger-upper-edge points and then find and plot the fitted curves a few times (or five):

```mathematica
lsPoints3 = SortBy[lsPoints2[[2]], First][[1 ;; -1 ;; 3]];
lsQRFuncs = Table[First@ResourceFunction["QuantileRegression"][lsPoints3 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 8], Length[lsPoints3]], 30, 0.5], 5];
lsQRFuncs = Map[PiecewiseExpand[#[x]] &, lsQRFuncs];
Show[ListPlot[lsPoints2[[2]], PlotStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7]], Plot[lsQRFuncs, {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[3]}], PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotTheme -> "Scientific", AspectRatio -> 1/3]]
```

[image]

Plot each of the obtained lines separately:

```mathematica
Map[Plot[#, {x, 0, 500}, PlotStyle -> Directive[{Red, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], AspectRatio -> 1/3, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", PlotTheme -> "Web"] &, lsQRFuncs]
```

[image]

**Remark:** The wavy curves can be "tuned" by using different number of knots and different random noise distributions

Answer (score 1):

We can use resource function [`RandomScribble`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RandomScribble/).

```
ResourceFunction["RandomScribble"][]
```

[image]