# How to add something like a shadow to my resulting figure?

Tags: plotting, graphics, complex

after plotting this function:

```
ParametricPlot[
 With[{z = Exp[I θ]}, 
  Through[{Re, Im}[
    1 - ((I 0.8) Log[(1 - E^(-((I π 0.2)/0.8)) z)/(1 - E^((I π 0.2)/0.8) z)])/π
    ]] ],
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Or alternatively, after substituting in the value for `z` outside the plotting function:

```
ParametricPlot[{1 + 
   Re[(0.` - 0.25464790894703254` I) Log[(
      1 - (0.7071067811865476` - 0.7071067811865475` I) E^(I θ))/(
      1 - (0.7071067811865476` + 0.7071067811865475` I) E^(I θ))]], 
  Im[(0.` - 0.25464790894703254` I) Log[(
     1 - (0.7071067811865476` - 0.7071067811865475` I) E^(I θ))/(
     1 - (0.7071067811865476` + 0.7071067811865475` I) E^(I θ))]]}, {θ, 0, 2 π},
     ImageSize -> Medium,  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

I don't know what should I add to make something as a shadow to the resulting line to separate the two resulting plans. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please fix your code so that it plots when we copy/paste it?

Comment: yes .. that is right .. it is just a vertical line and i want to add something as a shadow to that line to separate the two halfs..

Comment: You might look here -- for instructions on adding dropshadows to plots http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3058/how-can-i-make-a-2d-line-plot-with-a-drop-shadow-under-the-line