# Compile nested Sums

Tags: compile, summation

I want to compile an expressions that contains nested `Sum`-expressions. A simple example that gives me problems is:

```
sumsum = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Sum[1/Sum[i + j, {j, n}], {i, n}]]
```

**Note: This is not the problem I want to solve, it is just a simple example code, where the problem, which is described below, occurs.**

While the expression compiles, using `CompilePrint` shows that the whole evaluation does not use compiled code, because there clearly is a call to `MainEvaluate` when the first call to Sum appears:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[sumsum]
```

A quick fix would be to use `Plus@@Table` instead of `Sum`, but this combination is in general slower than using `Sum`. Indeed

```
Plus @@ Table[1/Sum[i + j, {j, n}], {i, n}]
```

Does not show any call to `MainEvaluate` and runs faster than the uncompiled code.

**Any suggestions on how to get nested sums to compile correctly? (once again, I am interested in a general solution to compiling nested sums, not a specific solution to the example stated above)**

Comment: If this is your real problem, you can easily get an analytic solution.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: This is of course not my real problem, but the real problem has the same structure. I edited the example slightly to show that there is a dependency on external data which leaves no analytic solution.

Comment: Then a quick analysis shows that your nested `Sum` can be written as `sumsum = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}, {n, _Integer}}, Module[{t = Total@data[[;; n]]}, Total[(1/(n data[[;; n]] + t))]]]`

Comment: @xzczd: Thanks for the comment, but the problem above is not the problem I want to solve, it's just an example. The introduction of data seems to cause even more confusion, so I will edit it out again. Basically what I am trying to ask is how to compile nested Sums efficiently.

Comment: Well, I believe the nested `Sum` can be generally avoided. BTW, according to my quick test, `Plus@@Table` is faster than `Sum`, and `Total@Table` will be even faster.

Comment: For me, `Plus@@Table` is slower than `Sum` inside a Compile statement, but `Total@Table` is faster, so this kind of answers my question. I always thought building a table first has to be slower, but it seems to have little influence in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Let me elaborate my comment into an answer. To make the nested `Sum` compiled, let's first have a close look at the compiling result of code containing one `Sum`:

```
sum = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 1/Sum[3.141 + j, {j, n}]];
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
p1 = CompilePrint@sum
```

[image]

It's not hard to notice that `Sum` is actually translated into a loop by `Compile`. It's reasonable to guess, if we express the summation with a loop instead of `Sum`, it will be finally translated into the same result, and it's true:

```
sum2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Module[{k = 0.}, 1/(Do[k += 3.141 + j, {j, n}]; k)]];
p2 = CompilePrint@sum2;
Grid[{{p1, p2}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

You can see the compiling results are almost same.

Manually replacing `Sum` with `Module[…, Do[…]]` is tedious, let's make use of code generation technique to facilitate the replacement:

```
sum[expr_, iter_] := Module[{k = 0.}, Do[k += expr, iter]; k];

sum2test = Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 1/sum[3.141 + j, {j, n}]] //. DownValues@sum // 
   ReleaseHold;

sum2test@1000 == sum2@1000
(* True *)
```

Then since the `Module[… Do[… ]]` algorithm is closer to the the one adopted inside `Compile`, it's reasonable to guess that `Compile` can translate it more easily i.e. it may be compiled successfully in a situation that `Sum` fails, for example, nested `Sum`, and again, it's true:

```
sumsum2 = Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, sum[1/Sum[i + j, {j, n}], {i, n}]] //. 
DownValues@sum // ReleaseHold;

CompilePrint@sumsum2
```

[image]

*Pictured by Simon Wood's [shadow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/43187/1871).*

Now the code is completely compiled and I believe it had the same performance as the compiled nested `Sum` (if it was correctly compiled).

Another acceptable solution is

```
sumsum3 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Total@Table[1/Sum[i + j, {j, n}], {i, n}]];
```

It's a little faster than `sumsum2`:

```
sumsum3[10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
sumsum2[10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {4.073000, 0.000109848}
> {4.156000, 0.000109848}
> ```

However, what I really want to say is, I believe a nested `Sum` is not the fastest solution for your original problem at all, considering the facts that most of the arithmetic functions in *Mathematica* are `Listable` and taking advantage of the vectorization is one of the most important approaches to speed up codes even inside `Compile`. Here's a vectorized version of your toy code:

```
sumsum0 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Total[1/(n Range@n + Total@Range@n)]];
sumsum0[10^4] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001000, 0.000109848}
> ```

Comment: +1 - a very well-thought out and clear answer