# How to draw a shaded elipse using drawing tools?

Tags: drawing

I'm trying to draw the following picture using drawing tools, but I could get just the arrows and points.

[image]

As you can imagine, I'm a begginer at mathematica, but I use LaTeX. I'd like to know if there is a nice reference for commands. I imaggine that we can't draw every thing with drawing tools, just simple figures, like this one.

Comment: MMA is not a graphics arts software. It can produce nice graphs/plots, but often companions of mathematical calculations... Anyway take a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsObjects.html)

Comment: Create the half ellipse, then use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43186/731) to get the gradient (think of it as a green shadow.)

Comment: I drow the 24 arrows with drawing tools, how do I do what you sugget with drawing tools? If not possible, how to draw these arrows at `Graphics[]`? Do I have to write `Arrow[]` 24 times?

Comment: *With the drawing tools*, this is not possible. You need to do programming (rasterize the ellipse, blur it, etc.)  That programming is going to be more work than what it would take to do this with a proper drawing program. There are free ones, like Inkscape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll build on David's answer (if you vote for this one, please also vote for his), since it's been a while since anyone demonstrated the excellent [shadow` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43186/how-can-i-add-drop-shadows-and-specular-highlights-to-2d-graphics) on this site.

We start by defining the arrows as in the previous answer:

```
myarrow[x_, y_] := Graphics[{
    Purple,
    Thickness[0.02],
    Arrowheads[.08],
    Arrow[{{x, y}, {x, y - 1.5}}],
    Black,
    PointSize[0.04],
    Point[{x, y}]
    }];
arrows = Show[Table[myarrow[x, y], {x, 0, 7, 1}, {y, 0, -4, -2}]];
```

Then we create the half ellipse:

```
myGreen = RGBColor[{165, 203, 149}/255];
ellipse = Graphics[{
   myGreen,
   DiskSegment[{0, 0}, {5, 1}, {Pi, 2 Pi}]
   }, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we use the [shadow` package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43186/how-can-i-add-drop-shadows-and-specular-highlights-to-2d-graphics) to blur the ellipse:

```
<< shadow`

glowingEllipse = shadow[
  ellipse,
  ellipse,
  "blur" -> 30,
  "offset" -> {0, 0},
  "color" -> myGreen,
  "outline" -> False
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, we put the arrow and the half ellipse together. We also add the gray line:

```
Show[
 arrows,
 Graphics[{
   Inset[glowingEllipse, {3.5, -5.5}, {Center, Top}, {10, 2}],
   Thick, Lighter@Gray,
   Line[{{-0.8, -6}, {7.8, -6}}]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How do I call a package for the entire notebook? I'm writing a textbook

Comment: @geekformoney You can load it (using << shadow`) anywhere in the notebook.

Comment: and how do i install this package?

Comment: @geekformoney There is information about that in the footer of [this](http://packagedata.net/) website.

Comment: nice. sorry to bother all of you with such simple questions, i'm a noob beginner. I never heard about this site for mathematica packages.

Comment: @geekformoney Don't worry about it, we were all beginners once. (Although sometimes we don't remember what it was like.)

Answer (score 3):

```
myarrow[x_, y_] := 
  Graphics[{Purple, Thickness[0.02], Arrowheads[.08], 
    Arrow[{{x, y}, {x, y - 1.5}}], Black, PointSize[0.04], 
    Point[{x, y}]}];
myellipse = Graphics[
   DensityPlot[(x - 4)^2 + (y - 4)^2, {x, 0, 7}, {y, -6, -9},
    Frame -> None,
    AspectRatio -> 1/2]
   ];
 Show[Table[myarrow[x, y], {x, 0, 7, 1}, {y, 0, -4, -2}],
  myellipse]
```

[image]

Play with the ColorFunction to get your desired green.

Comment: can this be used inside `Graphics[]`?

Comment: @geekformoney:  What do you mean by "this"?  One typically uses or defines an abstract object outside of `Graphics[]`, and then renders it visually through a call by `Graphics`.

Comment: `Graphics[Table[myarrow[x, y], {x, 0, 7, 1}, {y, 0, -4, -2}], ellipse commands]`