# Art on mathematica with filled circles and straight paths: how can I reproduce minimalist suns?

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art, drawing, design-patterns

I would like to know: how can I  construct minimalist images like this one?

[image]

Comment: If you want to fully reproduce the image including the drop shadow, check out the following post: [How can I add drop shadows and specular highlights to 2D graphics?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43186/731)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
  {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[.1, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]],
   HalfLine[{{0, 0}, Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ Subdivide[0, Pi, 50]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {0, 4}},
 Axes -> {True, False},
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black],
 Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

```
raylengths = {2, 10};

Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
   {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[.1, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, (Last[raylengths = RotateLeft[raylengths]] /. 
          2 -> RandomReal[{2, 3}]) Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, Pi, 60]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {0, 4}}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 Ticks -> None]
```

[image]

```
Show[LinearGradientImage[{Bottom, Top} -> "SolarColors", {300, 400}], 
 Epilog -> {Black, 
    {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[{.01, .1}, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]], 
      HalfLine[{{150, 0}, {300, 400} Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ 
         Subdivide[0, Pi, 50], 
    Disk[Scaled[{.5, 0}], 100, {0, Pi}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Since the color of the sun is inverted, also the background should be inverted ;)

Comment: Weirdly enough, `Axes` [seems to produce artifacts on export](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241505/63584), both in the form of a white line underneath the horizon, and a jump down in thickness at each corner. For this reason I'd recommend using something like `{Thickness[0.015], InfiniteLine[{{-1,0},{1,0}}]}` instead!

Comment: @thorimur, excellent point; thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Something like:

```
n = 50;
rays = Table[{Dashing[Flatten@Table[{RandomReal[.2], .01}, {10}]],
    , Line[{{0, 0}, 
      If[EvenQ[n ph/Pi], 2, RandomReal[{0.2, 0.9}]] {Sin[ph], 
        Cos[ph]}}]}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/n}];
Graphics[{
  Disk[{0, 0}, 0.3], rays
  }, PlotRange -> {{-.6, .6}, {0, 1}}
```

[image]

Comment: No horizon line ;)