# Art on Mathematica: How can I export 4K resolution png images?

Tags: plotting, graphics, generative-art, drawing, design-patterns

This question is solely based upon $[1]$ and therefore, the reading of $[1]$ could be interesting.

**How can I export the image created, by the code in the following, with high definition, beautiful, 4K resolution for an ebook cover/A4 dimensions?**

```
raylengths = {2, 10};

Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
   {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[.1, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, (Last[raylengths = RotateLeft[raylengths]] /. 
          2 -> RandomReal[{2, 3}]) Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, Pi, 60]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {0, 4}}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 Ticks -> None]
```

$$***$$

$[1]$ [Art on mathematica with filled circles and straight paths: how can I reproduce minimalist suns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241164/art-on-mathematica-with-filled-circles-and-straight-paths-how-can-i-reproduce-m)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this! One is with `ImageSize`, and one is with `RasterSize` (probably recommended), and they have slightly different effects.

Specifying `ImageSize` essentially scales up your graphics image first, and then rasterizes it for the PNG format. Since these lines in Mathematica have a width that is independent of the size of the image they're in, increasing the `ImageSize` will not increase the line width, and so the lines will appear relatively thinner.

It's possible that's what you want, but more likely, you want to have a high-resolution version of the graphic as you see it! You could potentially "fix" the above problem by adding an explicit `Thickness[0.0025],` (or some other number) in front of the `Line` expression (which might be useful anyway, as it lets you control line thickness).

Or, you can simply use `RasterSize` instead, which specifies how many pixels to break down the image into. `RasterSize` [can be specified in a couple different ways](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RasterSize.html) (see the Details section), but the easiest is probably by simply specifying the horizontal width in pixels as an integer. So, defining `graphic` via your code:

```
raylengths = {2, 10};

graphic = Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
   {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[.1, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, (Last[raylengths = RotateLeft[raylengths]] /. 
          2 -> RandomReal[{2, 3}]) Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, Pi, 60]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {0, 4}}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 Ticks -> None];

Export["minimalSun4K.png", graphic, RasterSize -> 3000]
```

This will give an image with a pixel width of 3000 (and thus a height of 4000).

For the sake of example, I'm using `png`, but there are other image formats you could use, e.g. `.tiff`, and I believe the same `RasterSize` option works for them as well (though I could be wrong about some of them).

To get it to be the right dimensions, you need to either fiddle with the value of `PlotRange`, use a maximum height in `RasterSize`, or crop it post-exporting.

To use `PlotRange`, you might want something like `{{-3/2,3/2},{0,3*pixelheight/pixelwidth}}`, or `{{-d*3/2,d*3/2},{0,d*3*pixelheight/pixelwidth}}` where `d` is a value around `1` that lets you fudge the "zoom" of the image.

I'm not exactly sure whether A4 is `297/210` or `11.75/8.25`, but if `A4ratio = A4height/A4width`, you could use it in the same way: `PlotRange -> {{-3/2,3/2}, {0, 3*A4ratio}}`.

However, this code uses `Axes` to produce the horizon, and that produces some artifacts in the bottom corners.

[image: An image highlighting an unintended jump in the bottom right corner.]

So, instead, I recommend

```
raylengths = {2, 10};

graphic = Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}],
   {Thickness[0.015], InfiniteLine[{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]},
   {Dashing[Riffle[RandomReal[.1, 25], RandomReal[.02, 25]]], 
     Line[{{0, 0}, (Last[raylengths = RotateLeft[raylengths]] /. 
          2 -> RandomReal[{2, 3}]) Through[{Cos, Sin}@#]}]} & /@ 
   Subdivide[0, Pi, 60]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3/2, 3/2}, {0, 4}}];

Export["minimalSun4K.png", graphic, RasterSize -> 3000]
```

where you can change the number in `Thickness` to your liking.

Let me know if there's any other way I can help!