# Horizon Plots in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create horizon plots in Mathematica similar to what is described here:

http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/2012/08/more-on-horizon-charts.html

Any suggestions how to approach this?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, VanFalk! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to [do more on the site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/privileges) (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: Please accept the following suggestion: When posting a question be prepared to remain online at least for an hour, checking comments and answers. If you disappear just after submitting your question, your chances to get good answers drop considerably. This time you were lucky! Verbeia was in a good mood.

Comment: I think you should illustrate some of it in your question. When that link dies (when, not if) your question becomes unanswerable.

Answer (score 6):

I am not going to give you the whole code for this, rather some pointers on how to get there.

To get a single horizon plot, you need to apply `Filling` appropriately. Unfortunately, getting different filling styles on different lines in a plot is not actually well documented. Here is some test data and a plot that does it correctly.

```
aapl = FinancialData["AAPL", {2007, 1}];
ibm = FinancialData["IBM", {2007, 1}];
msft = FinancialData["MSFT", {2007, 1}];    
aapl1 = {#1, #2 - aapl[[1, 2]]} & @@@ aapl;    
ibm1 = {#1, #2 - ibm[[1, 2]]} & @@@ ibm;    
msft1 = {#1, #2 - msft[[1, 2]]} & @@@ msft;

DateListPlot[{msft1, ibm1}, Joined -> True, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {Bottom, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]]}, 
  2 -> {Bottom, Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]]}}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> None, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, AspectRatio -> 0.2]
```

[image]

A `Grid` full of plots is easy to code up, but to create a function that takes a grid of plots and formats them automatically according to their position in the grid (e.g. hiding `ImagePadding` so x-axes are hidden for all but the bottom panel), you may find [my answer to a question of my own](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7695/8) useful.

My suggestion is that you create a `horizonPlotGrid` master function that takes a list of data, and `Map`s an auxiliary function `horizonPlotPanel` to each one.

The `horizonPlotPanel` function would look something like this:

```
 horizonplot[data : {{_List, _?NumericQ} ..}] := 
 With[{neg = {#1, If[Negative[#2], -#2, 0]} & @@@ data, 
   pos = {#1, If[Positive[#2], #2, 0]} & @@@ data}, 
  DateListPlot[{pos, neg}, Joined -> True, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {Bottom, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]]}, 
     2 -> {Bottom, Directive[Red, Opacity[0.2]]}}, PlotStyle -> None, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, GridLines -> None, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.2]]
```

You could also add the ability to add custom options using `OptionsPattern`. See [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/353/8) for more information.

Things to notice about this function:

1. The way I've used pattern matching `{{_List, _?NumericQ} ..}` in the function defintion to indicate that it's dated data (time series)
2. The use of `With` to define local constants, in this case the positive and the negative data as separate series. (There might be even better ways to do this, but this ensures that each series goes back to zero where the other series is operative.)
3. The custom `Filling` as shown in the other example.

To get the formatting you require, with horizontal bands as filling, I'd suggest adapting [this existing answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2988/8).

Answer (score 4):

A very "manual" procedure, just to help you get started:

```
ge = MovingAverage[FinancialData["GE", {2000}][[All, 2]], 100];
ge = ge - Min@ge - (Max@ge - Min@ge)/2;
s = Max@ge/2;
Attributes[f] = HoldAll;
f[x_, y_] := AppendTo[x, y];
Array[(l[#] = {}) &, 6];
(*for simplicity,we will work with all values>0*)
If[# > 0, f[l[1], #]; f[l[2], 0],     f[l[1], 0]; f[l[2], #]] & /@  ge;
If[# > s, f[l[3], s]; f[l[4], # - s], f[l[3], #]; f[l[4], 0]] & /@  l[1];
If[# > s, f[l[5], s]; f[l[6], # - s], f[l[5], #]; f[l[6], 0]] & /@ -l[2];

ListLinePlot[{l[3], l[4], l[5], l[6]}, 
 PlotStyle -> None, 
 Filling -> {
   1 -> {Axis, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]]}, 
   2 -> {Axis, Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.4]]}, 
   3 -> {Axis, Directive[Red,  Opacity[0.2]]}, 
   4 -> {Axis, Directive[Red,  Opacity[0.4]]}}, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note: The procedure above is manual *on purpose*, you will have to generalize it. Teaching to fish.

A `Sin[x]` horizon Plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
Plot[Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], Filling -> Axis, 
 FillingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y]], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Automatic], 
 Plot[(Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6)/3, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[y/2]], Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}], 
 Plot[(Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6)/3, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6, (Sin[Exp[ Sin[x]]] - .6)/3}, {x, 0, 
  4 Pi}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[{Red, Blue}, y]], 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
data = Accumulate[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 100]];
avg = MovingAverage[data, 10];
DateListPlot[{data, Legended[avg, "moving average"]}, {{2013, 1, 1}, 
  Automatic, "Day"}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> {{1 -> {Axis, {Red, Blue}}}, {2 -> {Axis, {LightRed, 
       LightBlue}}}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-(x + .45)^2/.005]/4, -5 < 
      x < -.3}, {-Exp[-(x + 0.15)^2/.005]/4, -.3 < x < 
      0}, {Exp[-(x - 0.15)^2/.005], 
     0 < x < 0.3}, {-Exp[-(x - 0.5)^2/.005], 
     0.35 < x < 0.65}}], {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> {LightRed, LightBlue}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(x + .45)^2/.005]/4, -5 < 
       x < -.3}, {-Exp[-(x + 0.15)^2/.005]/4, -.3 < x < 
       0}, {Exp[-(x - 0.15)^2/.005], 
      0 < x < 0.3}, {-Exp[-(x - 0.5)^2/.005], 0.35 < x < 0.65}}]/
   3, {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> 0.3, 
 FillingStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Piecewise[{{Abs@Sin[x], 0 < x < \[Pi]}}], 
  Piecewise[{{Abs@Sin[x], \[Pi] < x < 2 \[Pi]}}]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> {{1 -> Red}, {2 -> Blue}}]
```

[image]

And other combinations.