# How can I set different opacity values for the background of a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, color

In the following example:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Background -> Green]
```

how can I set the `Opacity[]` for the background such that the opacity increases from top to bottom?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.stackexchange.com.  Could you improve your question (including an example where you find your problems) so that it makes more sense ? Otherwise most likely it'll be closed.

Comment: `ListPlot[{1, 2, 3}, Background -> Directive[Opacity[0.1], Green]]`

Answer (score 16):

[Background](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Background.html) takes only simple parameters.

You could try this:-

```
lp = ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], Filling -> Axis,
   (* Default PlotRangePadding *)
   PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}];

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = {#1, #2*1.02} & @@@
   (PlotRange /. Options[lp, PlotRange]);

grad = Graphics[Polygon[
    {{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}}, 
    VertexColors -> {White, White, Green, Green}]];

Show[lp, grad, lp]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is to use `Overlay` and overlay the list plot with a gradient as per [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/problem-achiving-effect-i-want-with-colorfunction/15502#15502). Keys are to make sure your image size and image padding in both plots match up. In the `DensityPlot` I'm using the 4th argument to `RGBColor` to give the varying opacity.

```
Overlay[{

   DensityPlot[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 100},
   AspectRatio -> 2/5, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, RGBColor[0, 1, 0, x]], 
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> {535, 235}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{30, 5}, {30, 5}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0],

   ListPlot[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, AspectRatio -> 2/5, Filling -> Bottom, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {535, 235}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{30, 5}, {30, 5}}]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues one has to contend with when implementing gradients.

- First, `VertexColor` is unfortunately quite broken. It doesn't export properly to `PDF`, and it causes loss of antialiasing when drawing plots on top of polygons with `VertexColors` (see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14059/245)).
- Second, you would ideally not want to have to custom-draw the dimensions of the gradient background from scratch for every plot you create. It should be as simple as specifying a single option.

So here is an approach that tries to deal with these issues. It allows you to add the desired background uniformly to any plot by only adding `Prolog-> gradientBackground`.

First I define the background in such a way that it can **adjust itself** to any plot in which it is placed:

```
gradientBackground = With[
   {
    bottomColor = Lighter[Orange],
    topColor = Lighter[Cyan]
    },
   Inset[
    Show[
     Rasterize[Graphics[
       Polygon[
        {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
        VertexColors -> {
          bottomColor, bottomColor, topColor, topColor
          }
        ],
       PlotRangePadding -> 0,
       ImagePadding -> 0
       ], "Image"],
     AspectRatio -> Full],
    {Left, Bottom},
    {0, 0},
    ImageScaled[{1, 1}]
    ]
   ];
```

Now we just have to test it with a few examples:

```
ListPlot[{1, 2, 3},
 Prolog -> gradientBackground,
 PlotRangePadding -> None,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3.5}, {0, 3.5}}
 ]
```

[image: p1]

```
ListPlot[Sin[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/10]],
 Prolog -> gradientBackground,
 PlotRangePadding -> None
 ]
```

[image: p2]

In the above two plots, I've added `PlotRangePadding -> None` so that the background only appears inside the plot range. But if you want the whole region of the plot to be filled, you can do that by adding `PlotRangeClipping -> False` instead of suppressing the padding:

```
ListPlot[Sin[Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/10]],
 Prolog -> gradientBackground,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False
 ]
```

[image: p3]

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 Prolog -> gradientBackground,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image: p4]

The last plot shows that it doesn't just work for `ListPlot`.

Although I use `VertexColors` in the definition of `gradientBackground`, I then immediately rasterize it. You could leave that out and try the last plot again, to see how bad it would look without rasterization. To achieve the adjustability of the background, I wrapped the rasterized gradient in `Show` with the option `AspectRatio -> Full`, which makes the inset rubbery when I then specify the third argument of `Inset` to be `1` in `ImageScaled` coordinates.