# How do I change a ColorFunction filling to be top-down as opposed to left-right?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, filling

I've been stuck on a seemingly simple Graphics issue for quite a while now...

I am trying to make a temperature distribution Plot that will have a colorFunction filling to show red when at a higher temperature, then fading to blue as it gets colder, etc. My plot has temperature in the y-axis, and length (of a fin) in the x-axis.

When I try to put it into effect, the filling is filled with the gradient but it goes from left to right, along the x-axis. However, I want it to be fading top to bottom, to illustrate how the temperature decreases. One of my cells of test code is included below:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[T[x, length, h, P, A, k, Tinf, T0], {x, 0, length},
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, T}, 
    Directive[
     Opacity[0.7], (ColorData["DeepSeaColors"][Rescale[T, {0, 50}]])]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  ImageSize -> 200,
  PlotRange -> {0, T0}, 
  Filling -> Axis,
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
   AxesLabel -> {x, \[Theta]}],

 {{length, 5}, 1, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
 ]
```

[image: graph of the code]

I've tried a lot of convoluted methods like making a customized Raster image for the filling color, but I'm sure there has to be a simpler way to do this!

EDIT:

I want to be able to do this with the Plot function, so it is easier to Manipulate for the user. Right now I was able to get it to work by creating the data separately and then using a ListLinePlot, like so:

```
heatData = Transpose[{Range[100], Table[-0.5 x + 50, {x, 1, 100}]}];
bands = 50;

ListLinePlot[Table[{1, i} # & /@ heatData, {i, 0`, 1`, 1/bands}], 
 Background -> White, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
Filling -> True]
```

[image: graph of the code]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Closely related: [Can I make a plot with gradient filling?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2988/245). So in other words, it's not as easy as it should be, unfortunately...

Comment: Yup that was the one thread I stumbled upon... I tried that example out and it still ended up showing the colorFunction left-to-right... I guess a ListLinePlot ends up displaying different than a normal Plot? Thanks though!

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate.  As written it appears to be one.  If you have specific problems with solutions from the prior Q&A, or if you believe you need something different, please describe precisely how your needs differ from the prior question.

Comment: The code presented doesn't run on 9.0.1

Comment: I don't believe the `Plot` function has this capability, so the question becomes what is an acceptable substitute?  Heike showed how to use `ParametricPlot` with essentially the same appearance as `Plot`.  Do you understand how to use it?  Do you need help writing it as a function e.g. `myPlot` that automatically fills with a vertical gradient?  Do you need a specific feature of `Plot` that is not present or does not work the same in `ParametricPlot`?

Comment: Mr. Wizard, I would love to get help with writing it as a function! The way I had it above was what I was aiming for. That is, the entire function is already plotted, and what you adjust is the length of the y-axis so that you can "see" more of the graph. Thank you!