# Plotting extra parametric axes

Tags: plotting

We are trying to plot a figure as below from data points. This version is a postprocessed plot (in *Illustrator*) just to obtain the skew axes. The rest is plotted with [`ListLogLogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLogLogPlot.html). Any idea on how to add the "mixed" axes would be most appreciated!

[image: Plot with parametric axes]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Here its considered helpful to share your code attempts, hopefully is a well [formatted way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Do you need the tilted axis to be exported in vector form or a raster background image would be enough?

Comment: Perhaps you may find useful ideas [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39733/193)

Comment: And [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14149/193) for the arrows and labels

Comment: @belisarius, how would one go about getting those color gradients in the background plot? I was trying to do simple version of this plot and couldn't get past that part.

Comment: @JasonB http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2988/193

Comment: Please provide the data to work on.

Comment: Thanks a stack everyone - I am convinced this will actually do it. As soon as I have tried and have something to show, I will post a code segment and pic.

Comment: Hi, the data is in this table:

Comment: detectorData = {
  {"Solenoid", 0.005, 0.13},
  {"Planar", 0.03, 20.9},
  {"Planar", 0.47, 262},
  {"Solenoid", 4 10^-8, 0.36},
  {"Planar", 0.393, 13.8},
  {"Planar", 0.57, 163},
  {"Stripline", 0.012, 18.3},
  {"Planar", 0.005, 2.61},
  {"Planar", 0.00088, 8.66},
  {"Solenoid", 6.4 10^-5, 16.5},
  {"Phased Array", 0.77, 7730},
  {"Planar", 330, 92000},
  {"Planar needle", 0.5, 12.3},
  {"Planar Helmholtz", 10, 125.6},
  {"Solenoid", 0.03, 141.1},
  {"Solenoid", 50, 30},
  {"Planar", 1.2, 22},
  {"Microslot", 0.025, 7},
  {"Solenoid", 0.0001, 0.1},
  {"Microslot", 0.0106, 0.39}}