# plot filling using blend and y value

Tags: plotting

I want to plot say Sin(x) with colorfilling. but I want the colour to be a gradient between white and red. When Abs[sin(x)] is maximum I want white, when its minimum I want the filling to be red. In other words have a gradient of a single color.

I have tried

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6.0},PlotStyle-> Red,PlotRange->All,
     ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},Hue[1, 1, 1, Abs[y]]],Filling->Axis]
```

thanks

Comment: Please check the last example in the Scope-Filling Style sub-subsection of the documentation for `Filling`. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html . All you need, is to provide a different function to get red-white instead of the rainbow.

Comment: I tried that. But can't seem to make it work for two colors

Comment: Please show the code that you tried.

Comment: Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6.0},PlotStyle-> Red,PlotRange->All,
ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},Hue[1, 1, 1, Abs[y]]],Filling->Axis]

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** this isn't what OP had in mind, but I'll let the answer linger for the related and linked questions.

**EDIT 2** to provide a very brief answer for the intended question:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, y Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White}, Abs@#2] &)]
```

[image: Parametric Plot]

**Old answer**

That's a common mistake to make. The reason for this is `ColorFunctionScaling`. It remaps the range of values to run from 0 to 1 across the plot range. So basically, where `Sin[x]` is closest to -1, the filling is fully transparent, and where `Sin[x]` is closest to 1 it is fully opaque. The `Abs` here does not change anything.

First of all, you'll need to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6.0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[1, 1, 1, Abs[y]]], 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Scaling off]

But now it is white (or, rather, transparent) only very close to zero as opacity kicks in quite fast. If you must have transparency, you can, for example, replace the alpha argument with `1 - Abs[y]^3` or `Abs[y]^3` (depending, where you want red and where white):

[image: Different color function]

But if you ask me, the simplest way is just `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White}, Abs[#2]] &)`

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6.0}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Red, White}, Abs[#2]] &), Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Blend]

Note, that the filling here is white and not transparent. If transparency is necessary, you can try instead `(Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1], RGBColor[1, 1, 1, 0]}, Abs[#2]] &)`

Comment: thanks for your response. may be my question was not completely clear. Here the colour gradient is along x. I need something where colour gradient is along y, i.e. for the same x the colour varies along y.

Comment: I see. In this case this is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/can-i-make-a-plot-with-gradient-filling/