# How to fill curves with a color gradient?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

I would like to produce a graphic like this[image: rainbow]

but with a continous color gradient between the outer curves.

Is it possible to achieve this by using the `Filling` option?

Code for the sake of completeness:

```
Plot[
   Evaluate@Table[(Sin[x]+o)*x,{o,-0.5,0.5,0.05}],{x,0,4*Pi},
   PlotStyle->Table[ColorData["Rainbow", i/20], {i,0,20}],
   ImageSize->Large,
   Axes->False
]
```

Comment: Yes, actually there is an example in the `Filling` documentation under the Scope -> Filing Style.  I would start there.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think filling supports gradients in the y direction. For 20 curves as in OP appropriate filling between the curves would give roughly the correct result, but it wouldn't be a truly smooth gradient.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP It does support vertical gradients. The example I cited has one. Here's an example: `Plot[{x (Sin[x] - .5), x (Sin[x] + .5)}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, GrayLevel[(y - x (Sin[x] - .5))/x]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]`. But you're right, it won't work for a rainbow colour scheme, even though it does for grayscale. The reason is that it will only use linear interpolation between the two RGB colours on the upper an lower points. This interpolation (done by `VertexColors`) doesn't care about colour schemes, can't have all rainbow colours.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The ParametricPlot creates many small polygons in the middle, each of which will interpolates linearly between different sets of colours.  So now we can have a full rainbow spectrum.  It's also simpler than `Filling`.  +1!

Comment: @Szabolcs my documentation for `Filling` does not have any similar examples. Is this a new feature in 10.2?

Comment: I ask, as there was a related question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/can-i-make-a-plot-with-gradient-filling/ some time ago, where no such solutions had been offered. PS Obviously, it is not a feature in 10.2 as your code works in 10.1. However, like I said, I don't see the relevant example. Could you point me to the one you meant?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Sorry, you are correct.  That's a horizontal one.  My example above is a vertical one.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I see now. I never tried such an approach with anything, but `Hue` where naturally I got a solid red fill. Good to know, that `ColorFunction` can act on filling in such a way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Such a filling is possible with `ParametricPlot`.

```
ParametricPlot[{x, x (Sin[x] + o)}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {o, -0.5, .5}, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#4] &), 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

> [image: result]

Comment: updated to match styling in the OP