# Filling a 2D plot with a texture

Tags: plotting, filling, textures

I am having trouble filling the bottom of the following plot:

```
Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1}, {0, Abs[x] >= 1}}], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

with the texture:

[image: Texture]

I tried a few things, including:

```
im1 = 
  Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1}, {0, Abs[x] >= 1}}], {x, -2, 2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, r[x]}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, Black}}, Axes -> False];
im2 = image;
ImageMultiply[ImageAdd[im1, im2], 
Plot[Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1}, {0, Abs[x] >= 1}}], {x, -2, 2}]]
```

but with no success.

Comment: Related: [Can I make a plot with gradient filling?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2988/245)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `ParametricPlot[]` for this:

```
tex = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbuF9.jpg"]

ParametricPlot[{t x, t Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1}, {0, Abs[x] >= 1}}]},
               {t, 0, 1}, {x, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> None, 
               PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[tex]},
               TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #2} &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

Try using a region plot (I used an example texture but you could but any image in there):

```
RegionPlot[
  y < Piecewise[
    {
      {Exp[-1/(1 - x^2)], Abs[x] < 1},
      {0, Abs[x] >= 1}
    }
  ] && y > 0,
  {x, -2, 2},
  {y, 0, 0.4},
  PlotStyle -> Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Roof"}]]
]
```

[image: Texture]

You could use `Show` with `Plot` if you want the styling of a plot overlaid with it, and `Ticks`, `Frame` and `AspectRatio` to directly modify the `RegionPlot` to get closer to a `Plot` style.